# Best way to search through shell's history

Tags: shell, command-history

Is there a better way to search my history file for a command than grep? I do have some idea what the command starts as, but I don't know how far back in the history it is.

*update:* was formerly zsh specific but due to overlapping answers feel free to answer for any shell (or mode (vi/emacs)) here, just note if it is specific.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is usually the best way, as [descriptor said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541/best-way-to-search-my-shells-history/542#542). You can also use `!string`, which runs the most recent command starting with `string`, or `!?string?`, which runs the most recent command that contains `string`.

<sub>(I think that's the only stuff relevant to this question, but I covered much more of the history commands in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-prompt-features-or-tricks/67#67))</sub>

Comment: how do you make the 'ctrl+r' look like that?

Comment: @xen `<kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>`. [answer source](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/8e7e4562-2c1e-4a39-aea7-e10de7eec667/view-source)

Comment: I didn't realize SE engine accepted any html thanks.

Comment: I didn't knew that the kbd keyword would interpret correctly the "ctrl" and "+" ! I used to tag each key separately. thanks!

Comment: @OlivierDulac Sadly it doesn't, that's just how I used to format keys; somebody [edited my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/543/revisions) later to make them separate keys

Comment: ah ^^ well, ok, then it is back, in my mind, to a simple (and consistent) type of tagging.

Answer (score 36):

When using Bash, type <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> and then start typing. Typing <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> repeatedly after inputting some text will move you back in matching command lines.

Comment: That's only if you know the exact string. Fuzzy search would be helpful here.

Answer (score 20):

Not sure if this will help, but I like to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> and then start typing the command.  It should go through your history and present you with the first match.  To toggle through the matches just hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> again.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the zsh.  You might have to add this keybinding to your ~/.zshrc:

bindkey '^R' history-incremental-search-backward

Answer (score 18):

If you add the following to `~/.inputrc`

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

and restart Bash, you can start typing, and then use <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> to move backward and forward through the history of lines starting with the same prefix you just typed.

(Some may prefer to use `\e[A` and `\e[B`, which will replace the normal <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> actions instead of binding new keys.)

Comment: I prefer to map these commands to `Alt + Up` and `Alt + Down`.  Depending on the keyboard emulation the terminal emulate uses these combinations might be mapped either to `\E[A` and `\E[A` (e.g. KDE Konsole with Linux Key Bindings) or `\E[1;3A` and `\E[1;3B` (e.g. XFCE Terminal or KDE Konsole with X Free 4 Bindings).

Comment: do you know why some commands may break this in bash?

Answer (score 9):

The interactive prompt invoked by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, which had been already mentioned, is the most convenient way. Additionally it's popular to remap <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys to search the history for a prefix currently on the command line, however this requires some [changes to the `~/.inputrc` file](http://stackoverflow.org/wiki/Inputrc_for_bash_history_completion_using_up/down_arrows).

The classic and less interactive solution is to use shell history expansion. Typing

```
!foo
```

will execute the last command that starts with `foo` and

```
!?foo
```

will execute the last command that contains `foo`. More information about history expansion can be found in the [Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction), assuming your shell is Bash or compatible.

Answer (score 8):

If you add `stty -ixon` to your `~/.bashrc` file then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> will go in the opposite direction to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>.

Comment: I wanted to use `C-s` for this purpose, but [my terminal got frozen](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12107/4319); beware! (Well, I haven't yet employed any `stty ixon`, not sure what this is for.)

Comment: @imz: `C-q` will "unfreeze". It and `C-s` are the usual software flow control characters which were once useful to manually interrupt (pause) the flow of output when slow serial connections were used. Now output is so fast in most cases that what you want to see when you press `C-s` has already scrolled by. `stty -ixon` turns off software flow control.

Comment: Fantastic! I have searched for years for a way to scroll forward in history like this.

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised this hasn't been mentioned - but you can select vi-mode in bash or ksh by doing this:

```
set -o vi
```

...or using this as the contents of `~/.inputrc` (for GNU readline used in programs such as bash):

```
set editing-mode vi
```

Then after that, you can use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter *command mode* and use <kbd>k</kbd> to go back in history, and <kbd>j</kbd> to go forward. You can also search using <kbd>/</kbd> to search normally, and <kbd>?</kbd> to search in reverse.

If you use `~/.inputrc`, then this will work not just in GNU bash but in anything that uses GNU readline such as CLISP and possibly programs like the MySQL command shell and like the CPAN shell.

Answer (score 3):

I use following two most of the time.
But please note both of them search for starting chars.

1. **tcsh**:  type some few charecters of the command then <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> it will show the previous command starting with that key sequence press it again it will show another command.
2. **ksh** :  use `fc -e - <SPACE>` `<first few char for your previous >` this will run last command matching that sequence.

I was not able to find something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in Bash for my ksh and tcsh.

Comment: Ctrl+r works a little differently in ksh than Bash. Press Ctrl+r then type the string you're looking for *and press enter*. To search for the same thing, press Ctrl+r and enter without having to re-type the string. This is in `set -o emacs` mode, by the way.

Comment: @Dennis: +1 :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you type `!ls` then bash will look through your history and execute the most recent command that begins with "ls"

Answer (score 3):

To switch forward when using reverse search (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> command) :

1. Open your .bashrc file : 
    `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`
2. Add this line (the letter `f` can be replaced with another not yet used by the system)

   ```
   bind '"\C-f": forward-search-history'
   ```
3. Close your file and update your `~/.bashrc` (or open another terminal) with the command: 
   `source ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.bashrc`

Now you can move forward in the history with the shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

*might be zsh specific.* In researching [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541/best-way-to-search-my-shells-history/542#542) I [found](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_17.html#SEC100) `vi-history-search-backward` which allows one to search with <kbd>/</kbd> in vi mode (which I didn't mention I was in) you can then use <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd> to search forward and backward respectively (after pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>).

Answer (score 2):

I find [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#key-bindings-for-command-line) works better for this task, which supports fuzzy-search your command history. To install `fzf`, run the following command:

```bash
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.git ~/.fzf
# say yes to its install prompts
~/.fzf/install
```

Restart the shell, you should get a far better experience searching your history commands (the shortcut is still <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). To navigate the search results, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: Wow, this is *much* more feature-rich than all the other answers here (with the possible exception of `vi-history-search-backward` which I didn't try 'cause I'm an `emacs` guy)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> with **tcsh**. Add the following in your `~/.cshrc`:

`bindkey "^r" i-search-back`  (it is just a caret sign and the letter r)

That's the biggest time saver for me.

Answer (score 1):

similar answer to @ephemient, but you can put into your .bashrc

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-foward'
```

and type part of the phrase, and then use the up/down arrow to browse the most recent options that match. This is matlab's default behavior.

For most folks, if you want to port your settings to a new system, it is easier to remember to snag just your `~/.bashrc` then that that you have to snag that `~/.inputrc`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it exists, at least if you are using zsh. Just start typing the command and then press <kbd>M-p</kbd> (<kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd>) and it will find previous commands that matches what you typed. Press it again to find the next match.

Comment: This answer can do with more explanations.