# bash: recall command by typing some characters of it

Tags: shell, bash, command-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [best way to search my shell's history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541/best-way-to-search-my-shells-history)

In MSDOS I have the option to start typing some characters of a previous command and then pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> it will search the command history buffer for the first occurrence of these characters. Repeatedly pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> will continue the search for the next match.

I love this functionality! Does it exist on Linux/UNIX?