# Why can't Korn Shell do ctrl-r?

Tags: ksh, command-history, history, line-editor, pc-bsd

If I use PC-BSD with the default shell (Korn) then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> doesn't work. Why won't it work?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> was introduced to search your history in the late 1970s or early 80s and my BSD still can't do it (while Ubuntu can).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>  originates with Emacs doesn't it? When? 1975? 1983?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541/best-way-to-search-my-shells-history -- please see here .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> works with `ksh` in `emacs` mode (`ksh -o emacs` or `set -o emacs` within `ksh`), and it was most probably the first shell to support it. Only it's not as interactive as in `zsh` or `bash` or `tcsh`'s `i-search-back` widget.

In `ksh` (both `ksh88` and `ksh93`), you type <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>`text`<kbd>Return</kbd>. And <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> to search again with the same text.

In `vi` mode, you can use `?` to search backward and `n` for next search.

That `emacs` *incremental search* feature was added to:

- `bash`/`readline` at least since July 1989 as the feature was [already mentioned on usenet at that time](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/8APAYHZuTFY/y8t3Kpu57-0J) but probably not from the start as the version of `readline` shipped with `zsh-1.0` didn't have it.
- `zsh` since 2.0 in 1991 after the line editor was rewritten and no longer used `readline`.
- `tcsh` in V6.00.03, 10/21/91, but not bound by default (`tcsh` had other search mechanism on <kbd>Meta-P</kbd> for a while before that though).
- `ksh`: `ksh` was most probably the first Unix shell to have an `emacs` editing mode, written in 1982 by Mike Veach (as well as the `vi` mode by Pat Sullivan, reusing code that those two had already applied independently to the Bourne shell) at AT&T. ksh was first introduced outside AT&T at the [1983 USENIX conference](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/vhll/full_papers/korn.ksh.a) where [those features were described](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/net.unix-wizards/ksh$20emacs/net.unix-wizards/385HJUdrz5k/DxbzjC7xZSwJ), but was not commercially available until some time after that ([1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/net.unix/4JUURvwIOXk/YV1GIWIQme8J), [2](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/net.unix/l6s2xWKlnHg/lalgOmYVHRgJ)). It's hard to tell if `^R` was already there at the time (in any case, it was already there [in 1986](https://github.com/weiss/original-bsd/blob/master/local/toolchest/ksh/sh/emacs.c#L515) and 1985 (see `usr/man/man1/ksh.1` ksh85 man page in [that Unix V8 tarball at the Unix Heritage Society](https://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Distributions/Research/Dan_Cross_v8/v8.tar.bz2))), but it's hard to imagine it wasn't as it's an essential feature, especially for a shell, and I'd expect `vi` mode's `?` would also have been there at the time.

Answer (score 6):

The Korn shell does support history searches using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, at least since `ksh93` (and perhaps even `ksh88`), but they don't work quite like `bash`. First you need to enable Emacs mode:

```
set -o emacs
```

(This enables other niceties, such as arrow keys working by default.)

Now if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, the shell will print `^R`; type your search, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the shell will show you the closest matching history entry. You can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to run it as-is, or edit it.

Answer (score 0):

In the 1970s there was no cursor editable history for shells.

The first shell with integrated cursor editable history was my `bsh` in 1984 (based on a prototype from 1982). This history implementation uses crontrol-r to redisplay the current commandline.

In 1986, the Korn Shell became a member of the group of shells that implement a fully integrated cursor editable history.

A tcsh version with integrated editor first appeared in 1987.

Bash appeared in 1989.

Ksh by default does not run in `emacs` mode but rather in `gmacs` mode.

Note that ksh93 does support searching with control-r even in default mode, it just does not tell you that it is in that mode. If I type:

```
^R
```

I get this echoed and then can enter a search string:

```
^Rali
alias a=b
```

it finds the alias command in the history.

Comment: AFAIK `tcsh` had a command line editor as far back as 1983 possibly earlier.

Comment: ctrl-r originates with Emacs doesn't it? When? 1975? 1983?

Comment: csh and tcsh had a history but no command line editor at that time

Comment: Correct, it exists in emacs, but not in ksh.

Comment: @Programmer400, [earliest reference I've found on usenet was in 1983](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/net.emacs/XrsmPYYcsqQ/vad4va9x0MEJ).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Cool!

Comment: tcsh's 5.7 man page mentions: _Paul Placeway, Ohio State CIS dept., 1983 Added the command line editor._ Confirmed on [his CV](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pwp/resume.html)

Comment: Well, in 1987 people asked me whether I could add my command line editor to tcsh. I did not do that because the strcture of the code was really bad, there was no central input routine and so the only way to get the input was to call iotcl(TIOCSTI). If there was an edit at that time already, nobody did ask...Do you have the source code from that time?

Comment: I just checked his CV and he claims to have written this code between 1983 and 1988. I would assume that this was not available before 1988.

Comment: I have the source code for 5.4 from 1987 ([from usenet](https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=comp.sources.unix/v-q1qRVIpi4/TbAvM_gFD-gJ)) that comes with a rewrite of the line editor, the first version of which was written in 1983 by the same person.

Comment: Well, then it was available somewhere in 1987 after I have been asked to add my editor. Now that you mention this, I remember that a tcsh with editor appeared a short time after I have been asked.

Comment: [Arnold Robbins (of gawk  fame) mentioning working on porting the tcsh line editor to the Bourne shell in 1985](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/net.unix$20tcsh/net.unix/Q0TGwmag4e8/7A9pOvSkMw0J).

Comment: [`ksh` and `tcsh` line editing mentioned in 1984](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/net.unix-wizards/bSk7CnERCXU/CWaTREAAk3sJ) on usenet.

Comment: It seems that this  version of the Bourne Shell has never been published. I know of two Bourne Shell derivates that include a command line history editor: `ksh` (since 1986) and my Bourne Shell (also known as `bosh`) that added my `bsh`editor from 1984 in  2006. http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html If you can point to another working Burne Shell source with integrated history editor, you are welcome.

Comment: The posting in the usenet from 1984 you mention was after bsh added integrated line editing and ksh used the builtin command `fc` that saved the history to a file and then called `vi` (AFAIK).

Comment: [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/net.unix-wizards/bSk7CnERCXU/neAu2tL49YkJ) confirms ksh had vi and emacs editing in 1984

Comment: The ksh READMEs that come with the source mention 1986 as the first year where ksh offered an integrated history editor.

Comment: http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/net/dev/dev/user/tytso/projects/ksh/ksh.nroff also refers to a `vicmd` shell from 1981.

Comment: `ksh`'s default mode is not `gmacs`. It only is if `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` contains `gmacs`. If neither `$EDITOR` nor `$VISUAL` contain `macs` or `vi`, then you get a dumb mode (no line editing). And BTW on Solaris line discipline `^R` redisplays the current buffer like in your `bsh` it would seem.

Comment: I have no idea how you get to that assumption. While ksh88 did not start in edit mode by default, ksh93 does. At least since it has been added to OpenSolaris in 2008.  And BTW "line discipline" is something that has gone in 1987 when a modern streams based tty driver was implemented.

Comment: It only uses `gmacs` on Solaris because of `/etc/ksh.kshrc` there. With STREAMS, the tty line discipline is typically implemented as a STREAMS module. On Solaris, that's the `ldterm` module pushed on serial/pts/console... devices. If Solaris didn't have _line disciplines_, then it couldn't load different disciplines on serial devices like on other systems. In anycase, I was refering to the line editor implemented in that line discipline, and you can't argue that Solaris doesn't have such a line editor.

Comment: Actually, Paul Placeway's 1983 tcsh editor was [posted to usenet in 1984](https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=net.sources/3eER9GEdo2c/B9G1KGziIx4J), see manual with emacs-like (sort of) key binding.