# What are the best tricks to narrow down to the required command among similar looking commands during the reverse search of history

Tags: bash, shell, command-history

I have lines of codes all of which look similar. Giving some examples below

```
gmx trjconv -s md_0_10.tpr -f md_0_10.xtc -o md_0_10_center.xtc -center -pbc mol -ur compact
gmx trjconv -s md_0_10.tpr -f md_0_10_center.xtc -o start.pdb -dump 0
gmx trjconv -s md_0_10.tpr -f md_0_10_center.xtc -o md_0_10_fit.xtc -fit rot+trans
gmx trjconv -s md_0_11.tpr -f md_0_11.xtc -o md_0_11_center.xtc -center -pbc mol -ur compact
gmx trjconv -s md_0_11.tpr -f md_0_11_center.xtc -o start.pdb -dump 0
gmx trjconv -s md_0_11.tpr -f md_0_11_center.xtc -o md_0_11_fit.xtc -fit rot+trans
gmx trjconv -s md_0_12.tpr -f md_0_12.xtc -o md_0_12_center.xtc -center -pbc mol -ur compact
gmx trjconv -s md_0_12.tpr -f md_0_12_center.xtc -o start.pdb -dump 0
gmx trjconv -s md_0_12.tpr -f md_0_12_center.xtc -o md_0_12_fit.xtc -fit rot+trans
```

So essentially using `Control` + `R` just narrows down to this bunch of similar lines. But essentially I will have to evade through these bunch of similar lines to narrow down to the final one. I was thinking of some tricks.

```
echo 10step1 | gmx trjconv -s md_0_10.tpr -f md_0_10.xtc -o md_0_10_center.xtc -center -pbc mol -ur compact
echo 10step2 | gmx trjconv -s md_0_10.tpr -f md_0_10_center.xtc -o start.pdb -dump 0
echo 10step3 | gmx trjconv -s md_0_10.tpr -f md_0_10_center.xtc -o md_0_10_fit.xtc -fit rot+trans
echo 11step1 | gmx trjconv -s md_0_11.tpr -f md_0_11.xtc -o md_0_11_center.xtc -center -pbc mol -ur compact
echo 11step2 | gmx trjconv -s md_0_11.tpr -f md_0_11_center.xtc -o start.pdb -dump 0
echo 11step3 | gmx trjconv -s md_0_11.tpr -f md_0_11_center.xtc -o md_0_11_fit.xtc -fit rot+trans
echo 12step1 | gmx trjconv -s md_0_12.tpr -f md_0_12.xtc -o md_0_12_center.xtc -center -pbc mol -ur compact
echo 12step2 | gmx trjconv -s md_0_12.tpr -f md_0_12_center.xtc -o start.pdb -dump 0
echo 12step3 | gmx trjconv -s md_0_12.tpr -f md_0_12_center.xtc -o md_0_12_fit.xtc -fit rot+trans
```

After running these codes once. For re-running the code again, I use `Control + R` reverse search and then I put the string `10step1` or `12 step3`

I wish to ask if there are other tricks which can make this process more efficient during searching and narrowing down of the required line quickly

I went through similar history [search related questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541/best-way-to-search-through-shells-history) in other post but they are in general and does not deal with the problem of navigating through similar lines of code.

Comment: I suggest to append `# keyword` and search for keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Realine prompt is capable of [forward search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791765/unable-to-forward-search-bash-history-similarly-as-with-ctrl-r)

Alternativaly you can define a search function in your .bashrc
something like

```
function r {
   history | grep "$*" | head -5
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have setup my inputrc (can also be defined for just .bashrc) so that up and down arrows search history instead of just showing next or previous history. In this way, the up/down arrow commands behave like default on FreeBSD.

This is the inputrc snippet:

```
# mappings for Up/Down arrow to search through history
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

What this does exactly is, that if you type the following at the prompt:

```
echo 11
```

And then press arrow up, it will cycle through the history for those commands starting with "echo 11".

For me, this is much more intuitive, and it gives you the possibility to type in the start of your command, and cycle history for only that narrow selection.

If you combine with easy keys to cut away to the end of line, or cut one word at a time, you can get some very powerful search/browse options using up/down arrow history.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If we have the initial part then also the cluster remains same.