# In bash, how do I run the last command that contains a string?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-history

I'm using a bash shell.  Normally if I want to repeat the last command that begins with a certain string, I can run

```
$ !cat
```

What if I want to run the last command that contains a string?  That is, if I typed a command

```
$ cat dave.txt
```

and I want to run the last command with "dave" taht happened to be the above, is there a shortcut that will allow this?

Comment: Is `Ctrl+R` enough? That won't let you run it directly but it makes it very easy to find.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/541/117549

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `?` event designator:

```
!?dave
```

See `man bash`:

> ?string[?]
>
> Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position in the history  list  containing  `string`.  The trailing `?` may be omitted if `string` is followed immediately by a newline.

But I find it dangerous to call a random command from the history - what if I'm in a different terminal/directory and I accidentally delete something? <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd> is safer and more flexible.

Comment: A compromise is ``!?dave?:p``.  That searches history for the most recent command that contains `dave` and *displays it for you.*  Then you can pull it up again with (cursor up) or `!!` and modify it before you execute it.