# How can I apply caret-substitution to my nth-last command?

Tags: command-line, bash

I regularly find myself having to execute a lengthy command on a file, then process the results with other commands. To process the next file, I usually rerun the same command by hitting the <kbd>Up</kbd> key until I find the command I want and arduously replace the old filename with the new filename.

Is there a way to combine caret substitution (`^oldfile^newfile`) with the *n* th-last command? I have (unsuccessfully) tried to pipe the *n* th-last command into the substitution like so:

```
$ !-4 | ^old^new
```

Of course, I am open to other suggestions. These little shortcuts really help with productivity...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it with a [quick substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators) directly, because `^foo^bar` is shorthand for:

```
!!:s/foo/bar/
```

The `!!` part (which refers to the last command) isn't part of the quick syntax (that's what makes it quick), but you *can* use the longer syntax directly and then modify the `!!` to whatever you want:

```
!-4:s/foo/bar/
```

I explained as much of the history syntax as I know in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-line-features-or-tricks/67#67); the last section includes the `:s` modifier

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm after, though the title may suggest otherwise (didn't know about the `:s` modifier!). Thanks a bunch.

Comment: ...and `!!` itself is merely a shorthand for `!-1`.

Comment: @isomorphismes The [linked answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-line-features-or-tricks/67#67) gets into that (and quite a lot more)

Answer (score 0):

You could write lengthy command as a shell function that takes a filename as a parameter and then just type `function filename` when you need it.

Comment: I have considered doing this, but the nature of the command makes it more amenable to in-place editing.