# How to access the history on the fly in Unix?

Tags: shell, command-history

For example, if I do a

```
mkdir thisismyfolder912
```

I remember there is some easier way to switch to `thisismyfolder912` than having to do a

```
cd thisismyfolder912
```

What is that way and how does it work? Also, what are the other ways I can use this?

Comment: Use TAB-completion for commands and directories not in your recent history list. `cd this<TAB>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you talking about classic history expansion, or Readline processing? `cd !$` on the next input line will substitute in the last argument of the previous line, or <kbd>M-.</kbd> or <kbd>M-_</kbd> will yank it using Readline.

Comment: [Post on another question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-line-features-or-tricks/69#69) that discusses Alt+.

Comment: I was looking for `cd !$`. "Classic history expansion or Readline processing" I don't exactly understand what you mean...

Comment: @Lazer `!$` is a [history expansion](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-line-features-or-tricks/67#67); the shell processes it as it parses your command. M-. is a readline keystroke; readline is the library that handles each key you press, and it sees that you pressed M-. and types in the last argument of the last command for you automatically

Answer (score 9):

If your question is about accessing command history, then try this well-named command

```
history
```

You can also try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>, and start typing a command you're trying to remember that you've recently typed.

```
(reverse-i-search)`cd ': cd mydir/data/
```

Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to select the command or exit.  This works for me on SuSE at least; not sure about other distros.

Comment: WHOA! This is *actually* going to change my life. Screw you `history | grep ...`!

Comment: This is not just SuSE-related, I think it is a Bash feature :)

Comment: I just read about using `vi` to manage your command line.  Looks super cool.  [using vi to edit shell commands](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43003/using-vi-to-edit-shell-commands-in-unix)

Answer (score 7):

It's as simple as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

```
$ mkdir lasdfjalsdkjf
$ cd
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

```
$ cd lasdfjalsdkjf
```

Comment: How did you get the fancy box around Alt?  I didn't see it in the help guide.

Comment: @Banjer: use `<kbd></kbd>` tags to surround the key.

Comment: @Banjer [`<kbd>`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/2d868206-49e3-4483-9bfe-bf190ec7929d/view-source)

Comment: Also, this is the same as [jmb's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/how-to-access-the-history-on-the-fly-in-unix/1255#1255)

Answer (score 2):

this has always worked for me:

```
mkdir thisismyfolder
cd $_
```

Comment: Watch out for this, though: `$!` expands to the last word you actually typed, `$_` expands to the last word _after expansion_ - so you might `echo /tmp/tmpfile*` and see a bunch of files you want to remove, but then `rm $_` will only remove one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you use bash i suggest `pushd` and `popd`. You can create a stack of directory and browse it rapidly. See this example:

```
PWD:~$ pushd /opt/google/chrome/resources/
/opt/google/chrome/resources ~
PWD:/opt/google/chrome/resources$ pushd /etc/cron.daily/
/etc/cron.daily /opt/google/chrome/resources ~
PWD:/etc/cron.daily$ pushd /opt/pac/lib/method/
/opt/pac/lib/method /etc/cron.daily /opt/google/chrome/resources ~
PWD:/opt/pac/lib/method$ popd
/etc/cron.daily /opt/google/chrome/resources ~
PWD:/etc/cron.daily$ popd
/opt/google/chrome/resources ~
PWD:/opt/google/chrome/resources$ popd
~
PWD:~$
```

Comment: If you use an abbreviated prompt it makes posts more readable. (I'm referring to removing the user and hostnames. I understand that showing the PWD instead of just `$` is useful when demonstrating `pushd`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Picking up a tip from another thread, if you put:

```
bind '"\e[A"':history-search-backward
bind '"\e[B"':history-search-forward
```

in your .bashrc then, you can start typing something from your history, and then press the up arrow, and then rather than going through your history item by item, it'll skip right to previous entries that begin with what you've already typed.

I guess this doesn't help much with the particular example given in the question, but it is one thing that helps me access history on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

If your shell uses readline (which is the case for `bash`) you can do something like pressing <kbd>ATL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> together?

From the [GNU Readline documentation](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_15.html):

> **yank-last-arg** (M-. or M-_)
>
> Insert last argument to the previous
> command (the last word of the previous history entry). With an
> argument, behave exactly like yank-nth-arg. Successive calls to
> yank-last-arg move back through the history list, inserting the last
> argument of each line in turn.

Answer (score 1):

On a related note, I recommend using histverify in bash. Put this in your ~/.bashrc:

```
shopt -s histverify
```

This will cause bash to print out the command after expanding !$ or other history functions, and give you a chance to look at it before hitting enter again to actually run it.  For me, the sanity check is worth the occasional extra key press. Want to make sure I'm running the `cd foo` command, not the `rm -rf foo` one...

I frequently use the <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> approach, as well as <kbd>Alt-.</kbd> (which is a good fit for the scenario you describe).  I'll use !$ on occasion.

These are very useful general purpose techniques.

But to address your specific question:

Making a directory and cd'ing directly into it is such a common combination that it is useful to have a function to wrap it up..

```
function mcd {
  local newdir='_mcd_command_failed_'
  if [ -d "$1" ]; then   # Dir exists, mention that
    echo "$1 exists..."
    newdir="$1"
  else
    if [ -n "$2" ]; then   # We've specified a mode
        command mkdir -p -m $2 "$1" && newdir = "$1"
    else                   # Plain old mkdir
        command mkdir -p "$1" && newdir="$1"
    fi
  fi
  builtin cd "$newdir"   # No matter what, cd into it
}
```

Usage:  `mcd thisismyfolder`