# grep - why do brackets in grep pattern remove the grep process from ps results?

Tags: grep, ps

Why do brackets in a `grep` pattern remove the grep process from `ps` results?

```
$ ps -ef | grep XXXX

[...] XXXX
[...] grep XXXX


$ ps -ef | grep [X]XXX

[...] XXXX
```

Comment: This is a great little trick, in the first place!

Comment: Further answers for this question are given here  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78771/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-test-expression

Answer (score 24):

When you run `ps -ef | grep string`, grep is displayed in the output because `string` matches `[...] grep string`.

But, when you run `ps -ef | grep [s]tring` the line isn't displayed, because grep translates `[s]tring` to `string`, while ps outputs `[...] grep [s]tring`, and that doesn't match `string`

Comment: ...because `[]` represents any one of the set of characters within the brackets of which, in this case "s" is the only one...

Comment: yea... I really had trouble trying to explain this one in english... it's not my first language :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the brackets need to be escaped, for bash once and for grep again:

```
$ ps -ef | grep \\[X\\]XXX

[...] XXXX
[...] grep XXXX


$ ps -ef | grep "\[X\]XXX"

[...] XXXX
[...] grep XXXX
```