# What is the meaning of this test expression []?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, ps

I've seen someone use command:

```
 ps -ef | grep [h]ttpd
```

and Output is:

```
apache   25125 31006  0 21:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   26869 31006  0 22:04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   27349 31006  0 22:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   27696 31006  0 22:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   28534 31006  0 22:14 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     31006     1  0 16:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   31011 31006  0 16:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

2 brackets surrounding the letter "h" where the `grep` to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a trick to prevent the `grep` command itself from appearing in the `ps` output.

`[...]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) specification, i.e. `[ab2]` matches exactly one character that must be `a`, `b` or `2`. `[h]` matches only exactly `h`.

The trick is that `[h]ttp` matches `http`, but it *doesn't* match itself.

Comment: Why? `It's prevent the grep command itself from appearing in the ps output.`

Comment: If you do `ps -ef|grep http`, the `grep` command itself will sometimes appear in the output, which is not desirable. With `[h]ttp`, the grep command filters itself out because of the above.

Comment: Regular Expression will be handled by `bash` or `grep`?

Comment: By grep unless you have a file that matches the `[h]ttp` glob pattern in the current directory (that would be a file called exactly `http`) - in that case, the trick will fail since the shell will expand the glob. use `grep '[h]ttp'` to prevent this.