# grep command giving false positive results

Tags: shell

I am using this command to get a count of any proces running with a certain name (in a loop) and then further deciding on the count but sometimes it gives wrong answers for all the processes and sometime for few processes in the same loop. On some server there won't be any problem at all. When I check the same manually, it just truns out to be wrong

```
check_process() {
    process_count=$(ps -eaf | grep -v grep | grep "$1" | wc -l)
    if [ "${process_count}" -eq 1 ]; then
        PROCESS_EXISTS=0
        echo $1 " is running"
    else
        PROCESS_EXISTS=1
        echo $1 " is not running"
    fi
}
```

I also want to mention this that it used to work just fine for almost 2 years and only started giving trouble from last 2-3 months.

Comment: Is it possible that there's more than 1 process with a given name running.  Your script assumes if the count isn't 1, then it must not be running.  The answer could be, for example, 2.

Comment: possible but everytime it had failed, it has always been wrong. It says "service_name is running" when nothing is running and it says "services_name is not running" when it is actually running and when I check it, it has always been a single process running.

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/417043/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/578777/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/377296/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78771/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2062/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/295363/5132  , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37508/5132 .

Answer (score 3):

`ps -f` gives an output like:

```
chazelas   11042   10528  1 08:49 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 6 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 7847 -prefMapSize 699608 -parentBuildID 20200720193547 -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 10528 true tab
```

Doing `grep "$1"` to return the lines for a given process name is wrong on many accounts:

- that fails if `$1` starts with `-`. You need `grep -e "$1"` or `grep -- "$1"`. You should really get into the habit of using the end-of-options delimiter when passing arbitrary data to commands.
- `grep` takes a regexp pattern to match on (that's the `re` in `grep`). So `grep a.py` would match on `aspy` for instance. You can use `grep -F` to search for substrings instead.
- `ps -f` does not report the process *names* but the process *arguments* (including `argv[0]` which by convention is generally a path to the command).
- you're grepping for regexp/substrings, without restricting where within the lines it matches. So above for `$1` == `as` for instance, it would match on the `as` in `chazelas`. Or it could match on the other arguments than `argv[0]`.
- `grep | wc -l` is `grep -c`.

Here, there is a (non-standard but very common) command to match processes by name (or other criteria for that matters): `pgrep`

```
pgrep -xc -- "$1"
```

Would `c`ount the processes whose *name* (like that reported by `ps` without `-f`) matches e`x`actly the regexp in `$1`. With `-f`, `pgrep` matches on the full list of arguments (as reported by `ps -f`) instead of the process name.

That leaves the problem of process names containing regexp operators (like the `.` mentioned above). Unfortunately, `pgrep` doesn't have a `-F` option to do a string comparison instead of regexp match, so you'd need to escape the regexp operators in there.

Another option is to tell `ps` to only report the process names and then use `grep -xF` to do e`x`act `F`ixed-string comparison:

```
ps -Ao comm= | grep -Fxce "$1"
```

Replace `comm` with `args` to print the list of arguments (possibly truncated though, some `ps` implementations allow one or more `-w` to raise the line length limit) instead of process name.

In any case, any user can create any process with any name and with any list of arguments, so finding processes by name is quite brittle. Anybody can trick you into thinking your process is there by starting one with the same name and same list of arguments running a completely different command.

It's generally better to check for the availability of services that your process is providing or hold on some resource it's currently using.

In some cases, you can add other criteria to your search such as effective uid (`-u` in `pgrep`), or the path of the executable it is currently running.

On Linux and with `zsh`:

```
pids=(/proc/<->(Nnu[chazelas]e['[[ $REPLY/exe -ef /usr/bin/sleep ]]']:t]))
```

Would store in `$pids` the ids of the processes that are running code in the `/usr/bin/sleep` file as the `chazelas` user for instance and you can use `if (($#pids > 0)); then...` to check that that list is not empty. (replace `/usr/bin/sleep` with `=sleep` or `$commands[sleep]` for searching the `sleep` command in `$PATH`).

More generally, it's much better to rely on your service manager to manage services and processes. Modern ones such as `systemd` will provide facilities to do that reliably.

Answer (score 0):

1. There can be some weird timing effects in some cases.
2. Depending on what you are grepping for, there could be other matches.  It can be worth checking without the `wc`.  Due to the way you are checking, if there are two matches, you report it not running.  (I.e. consider using `-ge` instead of `-eq`.)
3. A more effective test can be to use `killall -0 commandname`.  Killing with signal 0 sends no actual signal, but still does all the error checking, including being an error if nothing was found.  (One downside: killing a process that isn't your own is also an error, unless you are root.  The `--user` option can help with this.)

Comment: I have always checked the proces count before fixing the issue manually (without "wc") and it has always been 1 process running or no process. BTW for some services in the same list on the same server, I am getting no issues. Also, regarding your 3rd point, I cannot do it as it is a must to stop the process properly using some other set of commands. Thank you for your though.

Comment: @gurmeet  You missed the point of the third point.  kill -0 DOES NOT STOP the process.  In fact, it doesn't affect the process in any way.  What it does is say "can I affect the process?"  And with killall, there is also "Is there a process for me to affect?"

Comment: Interesting....I'll experiment with this and if it goes well, I'll update you. Thanks a lot :)