# How to change what Alt+F2 calls in GNOME?

Tags: gnome

I saw [something that made me salivate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2505/which-run-dialog/2507#2507) and I want it to be the program that is run when I do <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open `System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts`.
Disable (or reset) the **Show the panel's "Run Application" dialog box**.
 Now **Add** a new shortcut and set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to the command you would like to start.

[image]

Comment: I'm running GNOME 2.30 on Debian and my __Remove__ button is not selectable. What are you suing? I was able to add it (gmrun) anyway, and reassigned the shortcut.

Comment: If you click on a shortcut the **New shortcut...** appears, now hit Backspace to disable it (like the green info indicates).

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work (__Remove__ is unselectable). What are you using?

Comment: You can't remove Gnome given shortcuts, **forget** Remove, just **Disable** it by hitting backspace.

Answer (score 1):

To start the keyboard shortcuts dialog from the console, type:

Gnome 2.x:

```
gnome-keybindings-properties
```

Gnome 3.x:

```
gnome-control-center keyboard
```