# What's a quick Launcher app which will do auto-complete?

Tags: ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which run dialog](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2505/which-run-dialog)

I'm a unix noob, looking for a good replacement to Windows 7's start menu (pressing Windows key and typing "Ch" will bring up Chrome).

I was told I can just press Alt-F2 to get a launcher, but it's a bit slow, and it doesn't seem to do auto-complete (at least not out of the box)