# How to echo a bang!

Tags: command-line, bash, echo

I tried to create a script by `echo`'ing the contents into a file, instead of opening it with a editor

```
echo -e "#!/bin/bash \n /usr/bin/command args"  > .scripts/command
```

The **output**:

> bash: !/bin/bash: event not found

I've isolated this strange behavior to the [bang](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/bang.html).

```
$ echo !
!  

$ echo "!"
bash: !: event not found

$ echo \#!
#!

$ echo \#!/bin/bash
bash: !/bin/bash: event not found
```

- Why is bang causing this?
- What are these "events" that bash refers to?
- How do I get past this problem and print "#!/bin/bash" to the screen or my file?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try using single quotes.

```
echo -e '#!/bin/bash \n /usr/bin/command args'  > .scripts/command

echo '#!'

echo '#!/bin/bash'
```

The problem is occurring because bash is searching its history for !/bin/bash. Using single quotes escapes this behaviour.

Comment: It also disables string interpolation :(

Comment: That's the point! You can add other arguments to the same echo command using double quotes and get interpolation on those parts.

Comment: So, in `echo`, is it always better to using `'` instead of `"`?

Comment: you can also use C style string in bash with `$''`. For example `echo $'1!\n2!\n3!\n'` prints each number followed by a bang and a newline.

Comment: Putting bang in single quotes didn’t help me when entering a multi-line string: ![bash—single quotes do not escape bang (for real)](http://i.imgur.com/5HVVTaE.png)

Comment: You can use variables mid string with single quotes if you wrap the variable with `'"$var"'` ... single quote - double quote - variable - double quote - single quote.  http://askubuntu.com/a/76842/334235

Comment: If you're gonna need double quotes afterwards (for interpolation), you can still use single-quotes just for the `!`: `echo '#!'"/bin/bash\nMore $things"`

Comment: @binki I get the same behavior but I think that's a bug with multiline string handling, using '!' on a single line doesn't have that problem

Comment: @phyatt that doesn't work, you have to terminate the single quotes to use variable interpolation

Comment: @kbolino You are right.  So the full example string would be: `echo '0123'"$var"'456'`, note two pairs of single quotes and one pair of double quotes.

Answer (score 21):

As [Richm said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/how-to-echo-a-bang/3053#3053), bash is trying to do a [history match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-line-features-or-tricks/67#67). Another way to avoid it is to just escape the bang with a `\`:

```
$ echo \#\!/bin/bash
#!/bin/bash
```

Though beware that inside double quotes, the `\` is not removed:

```
$ echo "\!"
\!
```

Comment: In bash, ```"\!"``` actually expands to ```\!```, not ```!```, supposedly for POSIX compliance.

Comment: @Mikel Sigh. So many differences between zsh and bash

Comment: This works even when entering a multiline string. Remembering to 1. be outside of a string when entering the bang and 2. use this method (backslash) seems to work with the least surprise in most scenarios.

Comment: Would be useful to note that bash doesn’t do history searches when executing a script, so no need to do anything special for it there.

Comment: Isn't there any syntax to simply escape `!` inside double quotes with no magic behavior? This is nuts...

Answer (score 15):

`!` starts a history substitution (an “event” is a line in the command history); for example `!ls` expands to the last command line containing `ls`, and `!?foo` expands to the last command line containing `foo`. You can also extract specific words (e.g. `!!:1` refers to the first word of the previous command) and more; see the manual for details.

This feature was invented to quickly recall previous commands in the days when command line edition was primitive. With modern shells (at least bash and zsh) and copy-and-paste, history expansion is not as useful as it used to be — it's still helpful, but you can get by without it.

You can change which character triggers history substitution by setting the `histchars` variable; if you rarely use history substitution, you can set e.g. `histchars='¡^'` so that `¡` triggers history expansion instead of `!`. You can even turn off the feature altogether with `set +o histexpand`.

Answer (score 7):

To be able to disable history expansion on a particular command line, you can use `space` as the 3rd character of `$histchars`:

```
histchars='!^ '
```

Then, if you enter your command with a leading space, history expansion will not be performed.

```
bash-4.3$ echo "#!/bin/bash"
bash: !/bin/bash: event not found
bash-4.3$  echo "#!/bin/bash"
#!/bin/bash
```

Note however that leading spaces are also used when `$HISTCONTROL` contains `ignorespace` as a way to tell `bash` not to record a command line in the history.

If you want both features indenpendantly, you'll need to choose another character as the 3rd character of `$histchars`. You want one that doesn't affect the way your command is interpreted. A few options:

- using backslash (`\`): `\echo foo` works but that has the side effect of disabling aliases or keywords.
- TAB: to insert it in first position, you need to press <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> though.
- if you don't mind typing two keys, you can pick any character that normally doesn't appear in first position (`%`, `@`, `?`, pick your own) and make an empty alias for it:

  ```
  histchars='!^%'
  alias %=
  ```

  Then enter that character, space and your command:

  ```
  bash-4.3$ % echo !!
  !!
  ```

(you won't be able not to record a command where history substitution has been disabled though. Also note that the default 3rd character of `$histchars` is `#` so that history expansion is not done in comments. If you change it, and you enter comments at the prompt, you should be aware of the fact that ! sequences may be expanded there).

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solutions don't work in, e.g., the following example:

```
$ bash -c "echo 'hello World!'"
-bash: !'": event not found
$
```

In this case the bang can be printed using its octal ASCII code:

```
$ bash -c "echo -e 'hello World\0041'"
hello World!
$
```

Comment: In your first command, the `!` is between double quotes, where as other answers indicate it retains its history expansion meaning. You could use  `bash -c 'echo '\''hello World!'\'` or `bash -c "echo 'hello World"\!"'"`.

Comment: Without the -i parameter, the environment may be altered (like your ~/.profile doesn't run). However, doing -i means any output from your .profile will be captured in the output of the command you actually want to run.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution not yet mentioned is to use a variable:

```
$ var='!'
$ echo -e "#${var}/bin/bash \n /usr/bin/command args"  > .scripts/command
```

---

Printing a `bang!` is **not** a problem when the string is unquoted or is single quoted or inside a C-String

```
$ echo hi\!pal 'hi!pal' $'hi!pal'
hi!pal 'hi!pal' $'hi!pal'
```

Nor it is a problem when histexpand is disabled ( either `shopt -ou histexpand` or `set +o histexpand` or simply `set +H`. It is also posible to change hisexpand characters to make it easier to print a `bang!`.

But the portable simplest solution is: use a var

```
$ var='!'
$ echo "hi${var}pal"
hi!pal
```