# Escaping a '!' within double quotes

Tags: bash, escape-characters, history-expansion

The bash manual entry for double quotes (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html) states:

> If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an ‘!’
>   appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash
>   preceding the ‘!’ is not removed.

Why is there a special case made for `!`? If I escape a `$` (for example) the backslash doesn't appear in the output (e.g. compare `echo "\$"` -> `$` and `echo "\!"` -> `\!`).

What do if I just want a literal `!` inside double quotes?

A limitation I have for this problem is that I'm unable to easily manipulate the form of the bash invocation. By this I mean I'm stuck executing the command using a single double-quoted string, i.e.
`my-command "a string I generate in an external program that may contain !"`

I can control how the string is generated, but I can't split it up on the command line (e.g. something like `"part1"\!"part2"` wouldn't work for me.)

Comment: `echo -e "\x22\x21\x22"`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou can you elaborate a bit more on your solution? Might there be encoding issues?

Comment: Would that work outside of echo? I don't see any mention of that kind of strategy in the bash manual page

Comment: How exactly does the string that might contain an exclamation mark get into double-quotes? If it's from a variable or command substitution (i.e. `cmd "$var"` or `cmd "$(othercmd)"`), then there's no problem at all. If you're constructing a command line to be passed to bash for execution, just replace each exclamation mark with `"'!'"` (that is, a double-quote, a single-quote, and exclamation mark, another single-quote, and finally a double-quote).

Answer (score 4):

Printing an string with a `!` is **not** a problem when unquoted, quoted with single quotes, inside a C-string, or inside an script.

```
$ echo hello\!world 'hello!world' $'hello!world'
hello!world hello!world hello!world

$ echo 'echo "hello!world"' >file
$ bash file
hello!world
```

The script example is an special case in which histexpand isn't set (by default). So, disabling histexpand (`set +o histexpand`, same as `shopt -ou histexpand` or simply `set +H`) will have the same effect and avoid the history expansion.

However you are asking for a double quoted string in a (default) interactive shell without breaking the string in parts.Fine, what about this:

```
$ a='!'
$ echo "hello${a}world"
hello!world
```

---

About the historical **Why?**.

> Why is there a special case made for !?

Because most of the ascii characters are **not** special (inside `"`):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "\a\b\c\d\e\f...\z \!\@\#\%     \$a \`date\` \\"

\a\b\c\d\e\f...\z \!\@\#\%     $a `date` \
```

Relevant text from `man bash`: *Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within  the  quotes, with  the  exception  of $, `, \, and, when history expansion is enabled, !.*

That is the way a backslash inside double quotes works in ancient shells, and [the POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03) reflects that:

> The <backslash> shall retain its special meaning as an escape character (see Escape Character (Backslash)) only when followed by one of the following characters when considered special:
>
> $   `   "   \   <newline>

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Bash not removing the backslash used to escape a `!` appearing within double quotes (to inhibit history expansion) has been reported as a bug several times on the [bug-bash](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/cgi-bin/namazu.cgi?query=history+expansion+double+quotes+backslash&submit=Search%21&idxname=bug-bash&max=20&result=normal&sort=score) mailing list.

The historical reason for this behavior that is mentioned in [the answer you already have](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/565047/315749) is indeed the explanation given by Bash's developer and maintainer. Quoting a bug-bash [message from Chet Ramey](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2002-03/msg00162.html):

> As documented, the `!' may be escaped only with single quotes or a backslash. Double quotes don't work because `!' is not one of the characters that are treated specially within double quotes, according to the POSIX.2 spec and traditional sh behavior.

From the same source, about how to handle `!` within double quotes:

> You can either turn off history expansion with `set +o histexpand' or use backslash outside double quotes.  Note that history expansion is not normally enabled when the shell is not interactive, so removing the backslash within a script should not be a problem.

(A few variations of the same statements can be found on that mailing list, e.g. [1](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2004-12/msg00280.html) and [2](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2008-07/msg00059.html), which also mention the relationship with the C shell).

If you can't use any of those solutions: various workarounds are shown in the answers to [How to echo a bang!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3051/315749), such as setting the first character of `histchars` to an unlikely used character or using the third character of the same variable to start commands you don't want history expansion applied to.

Comment: From one of the [posts](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2008-07/msg00059.html) you're quoting: "Double quotes don't matter -- csh doesn't let them
inhibit history expansion, so bash doesn't." As if the history expansion in bash were even remotely compatible with that from csh. FWIW and FYI bangs (`!`s) also expand within SINGLE quotes in csh, and they also look to the current command, which means that they can be used to pass arguments to macros. `alias echo2 'echo \!:* \!:*'`, `echo! a b` => `a b a b`.