# Why awk not accept ! as field seprator?

Tags: awk

When I use `!` as a field separator e.g. `awk -F!` it is giving error message `bash: !: event not found`. Why? It is accepting `awk -F"\!"`. Bash version 3.2.25

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact command you typed on the console that resulted in this error message?

Comment: It has nothing to do with awk, `!` has special meaning for `bash` when it's not quoted in single quotes.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/how-to-echo-a-bang

Comment: Are you sure that's right? That you get the error for `awk -F! {something}` ? What version of Bash is that? (`echo $BASH_VERSION`) The exclamation point is the special character for history expansion, but it should only do something if there's anything after it, which there isn't in `-F!`.

Comment: You need to learn how to use quotes, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`!` is the trigger character for Bash's [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html). If that's enabled, something like `!foo` on a command line gets expanded to the latest command that starts with `foo`. Or if there is no such command line, the shell gives an error, like here.

It shouldn't do anything as the last character of a word, though. This actually works as you intended in all versions of Bash I tried:

```
$ echo 'aa!bb' | awk -F! '{print $1}' 
aa
```

In more recent versions, `!` also shouldn't do anything before an ending double-quote, so `-F"!"` works in later versions, but not in 3.2.

A backslash or single-quotes will work to escape it, i.e. neither `\!foo` nor `'!foo'` would expand. Of course you could also stop it by disabling history expansion completely, with `set +H`.

With double-quotes it's weirder. Within them, a backslash disables the history expansion but the backslash itself gets left in place:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "\!foo"
\!foo
```

In the case of `awk -F"\!"` this works because awk itself removes the backslash.

Answer (score 10):

It is not `awk` that is doing this. It is the shell. `!` is a special character in the shell.

## What to do

Always quote your arguments. e.g.

```
awk -F'!'
```

Comment: I am already using awk -F"!"

Comment: @Kalpesh that's not what's written here in the answer. Look again - at the quotes being used

Comment: Linux is very, /very/ particular about which quotes you use where: 
Single quotes ( ' ) are the most protective and anything entered within them will be treated as a fixed literal.  
Double-quotes ( " ) allow Expansion to happen, including the history expansion that you're falling foul of.  
Backticks ( ` ) execute the command between them, allowing you to assign the result to a variable (although bash also provides the more sensible "$(" and ")" delimiters for this).

Comment: @PhillW. It's not Linux, it's bash. Different shells and languages have different quoting rules.

Comment: @PhilW Nice comment, but you are falling for the error of mistaking Linux and Gnu/Linux. Linux cares not about quotes. It is just a kernel, and knows nothing about them. Gnu is the other part of the OS, that lives in user space. It includes the shell (`bash`).