# How to include "!." in an string argument passed to a script called from the command line in Bash

Tags: bash

I need to test how a python TTS program reacts when a user input mistakenly two punctuation marks.

So I need to check the sentence "C'est un test!." (notice the **!.** at the end).

Consequently I input at prompt

```
  $ python3 /home/user1/TTS/bin/synthesize.py --text "C'est un test!."
```

But Bash then shows :

> python3 /home/user1/TTS/bin/synthesize.py --text "This is a test./configure"

(notice how "!." changed into "./configure").

"This is a test!" (without period) works but I need to test "!.".

I tried and replaced double quotes with single quotes without success, and I tried and escaped "!" with "" but it is included in the sentence sent to the TTS library.

I understood that "!" has a special meaning in Bash (well explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3074/538421)) and associated with "." it uses a previous command.

Is there a way to prevent Bash from processing "!." in the string and pass it as it is ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "I tried and replaced double quotes with single quotes without success" -- A success was expected.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I changed the sentence in the question to the one in French I am testing against (contains already an apostroph / single quote). That's why it failed, right ?

Comment: It won't fail if you quote right. Example: `python3 /home/user1/TTS/bin/synthesize.py --text "C'est un"' test!.'`. Here the string is double-quoted to some point and single-quoted from the point. The point where quoting changes is almost arbitrary; it's only important your `'` is double-quoted and `!` is single-quoted.

Comment: Thank you @KamilMaciorowski I get it now. I don't want to do that (parsing the user input, replace ! by "'!'", do all the edge cases...). I prefer the `set +H` solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the *history expansion*. You can disable it altogether by using `set +H` or `set +o histexpand` or by setting `$histchars` to the empty string, or here you can use single quotes instead of double quotes. Outside of quotes, history expansion can also be disabled by prefixing `!` with `\`.

According to `set --help` in bash:

> -o option-name
> Set the variable corresponding to option-name:
> [...]
> histexpand   same as -H
> [...]
> -H
> Enable ! style history substitution.  This flag is on by default when the shell is interactive.
> [...]
> Using + rather than - causes these flags to be turned off.

You can try running these commands for checking the differences:

```bash
set -H
$> echo "hello!."
$> echo "hello!1"
$> !2
$> !3

set +H
$> echo "hello!."
$> echo "hello!1"
$> !2
$> !3
```

Comment: Thank you `set +H` did the trick ! Happy to solve this annoying problem (I thought at first my computer had been compromised!!!).

Comment: @TiTuS if you run your code in a bash script ( like myscrip.sh ) the *history expansion* is disabled by default. But If the shebang  of your bash script is: `#!/bin/bash -i` the history expansion will be enabled. `bash -i` means that will run bash as interactive shell.

Comment: Good to know thanks for this piece of information @Edgar. Actually I call a python script that needs arguments to be passed on so it is not run from a bash script.