# Understanding the exclamation mark (!) in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, command-history

I used

```
history | less
```

to get the lines of previous commands and from the numbers on the left hand side I found the line I wanted repeated (eg. 22) and did

```
!22
```

at the command prompt and it worked -- executing the set of commands on the line I did at that time. I cannot figure out where the exclamation mark is used, what does it represent in terms of actions taken by bash, and where to use it. From the documentation I do not see an explanation that is 'tangible'.

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-line-features-or-tricks/67#67) might help

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but <ctrl>+R will allow you to interactively search your history and then immediately execute if you find what you were looking for.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

`!` invokes history expansion, a feature that originally appeared in the [C shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell), back in the days before you could count on terminals to have arrow keys.  It's especially useful if you add the current command number to the prompt (`PS1="\!$ "`) so you can quickly look at your screen to get numbers for past commands.

Now that you can use arrow keys and things like <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> to search the command history, I don't see much use for the feature.

One variant of it you might still find useful is `!!`, which re-executes the previous command. On its own, I don't find <kbd>!</kbd><kbd>!</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> any faster than just <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but it can be helpful when combined into a larger command.

**Example:** A common [pilot error](http://foldoc.org/pilot+error) on [`sudo`](http://www.sudo.ws/) based systems is to forget the `sudo` prefix on a command that requires extra privileges. A novice retypes the whole command. The diligent student edits the command from the shell's command history. The enlightened one types `sudo !!`.

Processing `!` in this way is enabled in Bash by default in interactive shells and can be disabled with `set +o histexpand` or `set +H`. You can disable it in Zsh with `set -K`.

Comment: I find Ctrl-P Ctrl-J to be pretty fast; faster than Up Enter, at least.

Comment: If you just want to run the last command, Up/Enter is fine, but if you want to add to it in some way (say, you forgot to `sudo`, or something), then you can do `sudo !!`, for example. That might be a bit faster than "Up/Ctrl-A(or Home, if you are lucky enough)/sudo/space/enter". YMMV. :)

Comment: @AquariusPower: Just quote it. Either `echo 'Hi!'` or `echo "Hi!"` or `echo Hi\!`. All do the same thing.

Comment: `setopt NO_BANG_HIST` in zsh might be more memorable than `-K`.

Comment: kudos on the `enlightened ones` :)
can't believe I've only been a diligent student this whole time...

Comment: Important to mention that if you leave a space between the `!` and the command you will be negating its exit code(Boolean `not` operator).

Comment: Another trick: `Ctrl+p`, `Ctrl+a` then type `sudo `.  Same number of key sequences typed as `sudo !!`, but I've got muscle memory from editing command lines this way, so it's faster for me.

Answer (score 72):

If there isn't a longer answer here there's certainly one on Super User, since I've read one recently. In the [bash man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction) you can find a huge section titled **HISTORY EXPANSION** on the matter.

You can do a whole host more than just run the last command, or command number X.  You can do things like `!cat` to run the last command that started with `cat`.  Or `!?bash?:s/bash/csh/` runs the last command containing `bash` but replaces it with `csh`.

Comment: Although not directly an answer to OP's question, this needs way more upvotes. So useful! Thanks, Havok.

Comment: Uh, I should really look into the man page before I start googling.

Comment: `!!:s/bash/csh/` actually runs the *last command*, then replaces bash with csh, if present. Not the last command that included bash. That would be `!?bash?:s/bash/csh/` or maybe `!?bash?:s/%/csh/`

Comment: Having used Bash extensively for several years, I was shocked to find that I had never known about this keyword before, and even though I have spent hours poring through the `man` pages, this feature is incredibly obscure. Thank you for pointing out the relevant section--that's the only place in the actual docs where they explain it sufficiently.

Answer (score 54):

A lot more can be done with `!` such as:

- execute a command which is typed before 3 commands: `!-3`
- execute a command that starts with `!ls`

and a lot more. See [15 Linux Bash History Expansion Examples You Should Know](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/bash-history-expansion/)

Comment: Upvoted this. None of the other answers had any of these clever tricks.

Comment: Upvoted because www.thegeekstuff.com is simply a fantastic resource, and this was one of the few linux articles I hadn't seen before. Very helpful.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 15):

Of course you can do `!!` to reuse the last command in bash shell. And then there is `!$` to reuse the last part of your last command.

e.g. view some file

```
less path/to/your/file.txt
```

If you now want to edit the same file, you can use `!$` to get only the file path from the last command

```
vim !$
```

---

EDIT:

You can use all the arguments of the previous command with `!*`

e.g.: This will create some files and remove all of them

```
$ touch a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt
$ rm !*
```

Again , you can use a specific argument of the previous command

e.g. This creates 4 files and will remove the 3rd file (c.txt)

```
$ touch a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt
$ rm !:3
```

Similarly, you can use a range of arguments from the last command as follows

```
$ touch a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt
$ rm !:2-4
```

This will reuse arguments 2 to 4 which evaluates the expression to `rm b.txt c.txt d.txt`

Comment: Ah, I was hoping to find this. How does it behave with two args?

Comment: It'll just reuse the last argument of the two. `$touch f1 f2` and then `$vim !$` will evaluate to `$vim f2`

Comment: There's also a way to reuse argument ranges. I don't remember the exact syntax, but it would go something like this: `!:2-`

Comment: @SridharSarnobat Yeah apparently you can. Just a did a small research and it's super useful. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 6):

A friend of mine emailed me this:

> It's part of GNU history library.  In bash it is used to re-run
>   commands in your history.  If you want to be hardcore, grep for
>   history_expansion_char in bash-4.1/lib/readline/histexpand.c for
>   implementation details.