# How to write "!" symbol between double quotes in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, history-expansion

I can't figure out how to write `!` symbol in bash scripts when putting it in double quotes strings.

For example:

```
var="hello! my name is $name! bye!"
```

Something crazy happens:

```
$ age=20
$ name='boda'
$ var="hello! my name is $name! bye!"
```

When I press enter at last command the command repeats itself (types itself) without the last `!`:

```
$ var="hello! my name is $name! bye"
```

If I press enter again

```
$ var="hello! my name is $name bye"
```

If i press enter again it disappears nothing gets output

```
$
```

If I try this:

```
$ echo "hello\! my name is $name\! bye\!"
```

Then it outputs: `hello\! my name is boda\! bye\!`

If i use single quotes then my name doesn't get expanded:

```
$ echo 'hello! my name is $name! bye!'
```

Outputs are: `hello! my name is $name! bye!`

I have it working this way:

```
$ echo "hello"'!'" my name is $name"'!'" bye"'!'
```

But it's one big mess with `"` and `'` impossible to understand/edit/maintain/update.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `$ echo 'hello! my name is '"$name"'! bye!'`

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/1006777/4714

Comment: Or on this site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19252/why-does-the-exclamation-mark-sometimes-upset-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered, `!` doesn't trigger history expansion inside single-quotes.

You could use `printf` with a format string containing the `!` symbols in single quotes.  For example:

```sh
$ name="boda"
$ printf 'hello! my name is %s! bye!\n' "$name"
hello! my name is boda! bye!
```

or

```sh
$ name="boda"
$ var=$(printf 'hello! my name is %s! bye!\n' "$name")
$ echo "$var"
hello! my name is boda! bye!
```

Answer (score 2):

Disable history expansion; which is only enabled in interactive shells, via: `set +H`.