# Retrieving lines from a file depending on other lines

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

Imagine the following file structure:

```
foo.bar.1
blabla
moreblabla
relevant=yes
foo.bar.2
relevant=no
foo.bar.3
blablabla
foo.bar.4
relevant=yes
```

I want to retrieve all `foo.bar` lines where within the block following themselves and before the next `foo.bar` there is a line stating `relevant=yes`.

So the output should be:

```
foo.bar.1
foo.bar.4
```

I could of course write a program/script iterating through the lines, remembering the `foo.bars` and print them when there is a line saying `relevant=yes` following them an before the next `foo.bar`. But I thought there might be an *out-of-the* box way using standard Unix utilities (grep/sed/awk)?

Thanx for any hints!

Comment: Chose awk solution as "answer" for being the clearest one in syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the input is processed line by line, then processing needs to go like this:

- if the current line is `foo.bar`, store it, forgetting any previous `foo.bar` line that wasn't enabled for output;
- if the current line is `relevant=yes`, this enables the latest `foo.bar` for output.

This kind of reasoning is a job for awk. (It can also be done in sed if you like pain.)

```
awk '
    /^foo\.bar/ { foobar = $0 }
    /^relevant=yes$/ {if (foobar != "") {print foobar; foobar = ""}}
'
```

Comment: Thanks for giving this awk solution. Pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way with `sed`:

```
sed '/foo\.bar/h;/relevant=yes/!d;x;/foo\.bar/!d' infile
```

Lines matching `foobar` are copied to `h`old space. All lines, except those matching `relevant=yes` are `d`eleted. E`x`change hold space with pattern space (this only happens when lines match `relevant=yes`) and `d`elete if it doesn't match `foobar`.

Comment: I get an `bash: !d': event not found`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @userunknown - [you're using `bash`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19252)... try with `! d` that is, insert a space after each `!` or try `set +H` before running the `sed` command

Comment: Thanks for giving this sed solution as well. Looks a little more painful than the awk-one imho as Gilles pointed out above. ;-) But I like it just as well.

Comment: @hal9000 - You're welcome ! I don't quite understand what's so painful about it but let's leave it at that.

Comment: @don_crissti - Sorry, sounded a little unfair. I admit it not being painful. It is just a very very little less straight-forward than awk imho. Was more catching the term Gilles used. Explanation: For someone not knowing sed perfectly well (count me in), the concept of spaces and exchanging them doesn't come clear just by looking at the syntax. The awk solution might be easier to grasp if you do not know either sed nor awk. But again, I loved to see a sed solution to this. This is why I pointed sed out as a tag.

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic way:

```
>>> with open("/home/xieerqi/textfile.txt") as file:
...   for line in file:
...       if line.__contains__("foo"):
...          VAR = line
...       if line.__contains__("relevant=yes"):
...          print VAR
... 
foo.bar.1

foo.bar.4
```

Put together in a script:

```
DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ chmod +x  relevance.py                                       

DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ./relevance.py textfile.txt                                  
foo.bar.1
foo.bar.4

DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ cat relevance.py                                             
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
   for line in file:
       if line.__contains__("foo"):
          VAR = line.strip("\n")
       if line.__contains__("relevant=yes"):
          print VAR
```

Comment: Thank you for the python solution though I prefer the other two solutions in this case. They are shorter and are what I meant when writing "out-of-the-box" in my initial question. But in the end your solution is just as fine. One thing though is taht when the pattern is a regular expression. awk and sed can handle them immediately whereas Python needs to be modified a little. (import re)

Comment: :)  Fair comment - awk and sed are always better for text processing, and I do prefer them myself ( in fact awk is a big part of my reputation on the other site, askubuntu.com ), however both sed and awk solutions have been posted, so I thought I'd bright something else to the table. Hope in the end my answer was beneficial in some way to you and other users !