# linux find command for filenames without extension for unknown extensions

Tags: find, filenames

I like using the following command to print file names but it prints them with extensions.

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\n'
```

In my directory, there are many files with different extensions. I tried adding `--ignore='*.*'` both before and after `-printf`, but it didn't work.
example; I have files myfile1.txt, myfile2.mp3, etc. I need it prints myfile1, myfile2, etc.
How would I do this?

Comment: Since you specifically ask about `find` I’ll provide this aside in a comment. You can do this fluently with modern native bash: `shopt -s globstar; files=(**/*); printf '%s\n' "${files[@]%.*}"` — this could have odd behavior if a directory in the path has a `.` in it _and_ the files in that path have no `.`, but I assume that combination is unlikely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (**I didn't, see second part of the answer**), you want to avoid listing filenames that contain a dot character.

This will do that:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.*'
```

The filename globbing pattern `*.*` would match any filename containing at least one dot.  The preceding `!` negates the sense of the match, which means that the pathnames that gets through to the end will be those of files that have no dots in their names. In *really ancient* shells, you may want to escape the `!` as `\!` (or update your Unix installation). The lone `!` won't invoke [`bash`'s history expansion facility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19252).

To print only the filename component of the found pathname, with GNU `find`:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.*' -printf '%f\n'
```

With standard `find` (or GNU `find` for that matter):

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.*' -exec basename {} \;
```

Before using this in a command substitution in a loop, see "[Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)".

---

To list all filenames, and at the same time remove everything after the last dot in the name ("remove the extension"), you may use

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        pathname=$( basename "$pathname" )
        printf "%s\n" "${pathname%.*}"
    done' sh {} +
```

This would send all found pathnames of all files to a short shell loop.  The loop would take each pathname and call `basename` on it to extract the filename component of the pathname, and then print the resulting string with everything after the last dot removed.

The parameter expansion `${pathname%.*}` means "remove the shortest string matching `.*` (a literal dot followed by arbitrary text) from the end of the value of `$pathname`".  It would have the effect of removing a filename suffix after the last dot in the filename.

For more info about `find ... -exec ... {} +`, see e.g. "[Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)".

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have tried all three, but they don't print anything. Am I missing something, on the same terminal, in the same directory find . -type f -printf '%f\n' works but as I asked in the question I need them without extensions.

Comment: @kutlus In that case, I (and the others) may have misunderstood your question.  Do you want to _remove_ everything after the last dot in the filename?

Comment: I just want the file name, example; some files are  myfile1.txt, myfile2.mp3,  i want it prints myfile1, myfile2. sorry if my questions wasn`t clear, thanks

Comment: @kutlus See updated answer.

Comment: Dear Kusalananda, thanks again for the very helpful answer. I have posted a new question closely related to this one, I wish you see it. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496339/how-to-write-linux-find-command-with-for-loop-on-jupyter

Answer (score 4):

In Linux, there is no such thing as a file extension.  A `.` in a file name has no significance whatsoever (notwithstanding that a `.` as the *first* character in a filename identifies it as a hidden file).

Also, checking the manual page for `find` on my system shows no `--ignore` option.

That said, if you want to ignore any files with a `.` in their name, you can use `find`'s `-not` operator:

```
find -type f -not -name '*.*' -print
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn`t print anything.

Comment: If this does not print anything, then all files must have a `.` in their names.

Answer (score 2):

As other's have pointed out, "extensions" don't really mean anything to Unix systems.  But we can remove them from a listing with a simple `sed` command.

e.g.

```
find * -type f -print | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'
```

If there are directories and you don't want them to be shown in the listing then

```
find * -type f -printf "%f\n" | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'
```

For a single directory we can just use `ls` instead of `find`

```
ls | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
find . -type f \! -name '*.*' -print
```

where

- `\!` : not (! must be escaped)
- `name '*.*'` : filename with extension

Comment: arg, not fast enough !!

Comment: Having to escape `!` is why I usually suggest using `-not`.

Comment: well it work w/o escape, I've been escaping it ever since SunOS 3.X... sight.

Comment: thanks but this doesn`t print anything.

Comment: In what shell do you need to escape it? It works without escaping in both zsh and bash. Both these shells only interpret a history expansion when the ! is accompanied by another character.