# How to write linux find command with for loop on Jupyter

Tags: linux

I am able to have a list of file names in a list named 'a' using the linux terminal command on Jupiter as follows;

```
a=!find . -type f \! -name '*.*' -print
```

To have the files names without extensions, the corresponding command works on linux terminal;

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        pathname=$( basename "$pathname" )
        printf "%s\n" "${pathname%.*}"
    done' sh {} +
```

But how can I  run this command on Jupyter assigning it to a name 'a' like above. The below code didn`t work.

```
a=!find . -type f -exec sh -c '
        for pathname do
            pathname=$( basename "$pathname" )
            printf "%s\n" "${pathname%.*}"
        done' sh {} +
```

I have tried changing the indentation of lines as well, i get syntax error, or nothing. From my search on the command line of for loop on Jupiter the '!' should be perhaps in a different location. How can I make it work?

Comment: Define "didn't work".  How is it not working as expected or intended?  Why are you not using Python's internal file traversal rather than escaping out to a shell?  Are you aware that there is no such thing as an "file extension" in a POSIX environment?

Comment: thanks. I meant if i preserve to indentation i get invalid syntax for 'pathname do', if i remove the indentations, nothing happens but when i print 'a' i get ''sh: 1: sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")''. I am not familiar with Python's internal file traversal or the POSIX environment yet.

Comment: You may need to escape the newlines by ending each line of the multi-line quoted content with a backslash, or just deal with it being one ugly line and get rid of the newlines altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in a different way if anyone has a similar issue. I used the command line
 `a=!find . -type f \! -name '*.*' -print`

this created a list of filenames with extensions. I removed the extensions from each element.

```
files = [os.path.splitext(fname)[0] for fname in a]
```