# Exclamation mark in the bash script vs in the terminal

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a simple bash script called *foo.sh* like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Foo!"
```

When I run it as `./foo.sh` I get the `Foo!` message and everything's fine.
But if I `echo "Foo!"` directly from the console, then I obtain the expected behavior and message: `bash: !": event not found`.

I understand that the `!` is presented as a previous command and if used inside p.e. single quotes, then it's considered as a literal.
I'm just wondering what is the difference here that running a script with that `echo "Foo!"` (even with `source ./foo.sh` works but directly from the console it doesn't.

Comment: Related - [Understanding the exclamation mark (!) in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3748/100397)

Comment: I guess technically, this actually isn't a duplicate of any earlier ones, since on closer look, they don't exactly mention that history expansion is only enabled by default on interactive shells, not in scripts. Argh.

Comment: Also, btw, newer versions of Bash (4.4 or so) don't trigger history expansion for cases like `"foo!"`, where the bang is at the end of a quoted string.

Comment: You mean that it's not enabled in the interactive shell by default?

Comment: @pangas, I mean that history expansion is enabled by default in an interactive Bash. And disabled by default in a non-interactive one. I don't think that's different between Bash versions. But there's variation between versions with `"foo!"` and maybe some other similar ones.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, interactive bash shells have history expansion enabled (which is what controls the behaviour of `!`). Sourced files (which exist largely outside of the concept of history expansion) and scripts do not. From `man bash` (or the [online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)):

> `set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [-o option-name] [arg ...]`
> `-H`: Enable `!` style history substitution. This option is on by default when the shell is interactive.

This behaviour can be adjusted manually with `set [+-]H`, or `set [+-]o histexpand`, where `-H`/`-o` *enables* history expansion, and `+H`/`+o` *disables* it.

See also e.g.:

- [Why does the exclamation mark `!` sometimes upset bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19252/why-does-the-exclamation-mark-sometimes-upset-bash)
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html