# Ctrl-Y, emacs styled yank text is not working when user is switched

Tags: bash, clipboard, line-editor

I cut the bash command line text using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. The line was cut as expected.  Next, I ran `sudo su` to become the root user.

I tried to paste the command that I cut as the non-sudo user using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. It is no longer available.

How can I use cut, copy and paste in bash shell across user sessions?

Comment: Take a look at files like `.bashrc` or `.inputrc` inside `/root` to see whether they are set correctly.

Comment: This is not related to your question, but there's never any point in running `sudo su`. Just run `sudo -i` or `su` if you have enabled the root account.

Comment: When you switch user, you are getting a new interactive process. The buffer that your command Yanks to is in the memory of, and hence local to the shell that you were using.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> saves text in the `Readline`'s buffer.
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> extracts text from that buffer.
Each Bash instance has own buffer.

I suppose that you want to run a previous command as `root`. Try `sudo !!`. Details in [Understanding the exclamation mark (!) in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/understanding-the-exclamation-mark-in-bash)

Use [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) for a complex copypasting across sessions/shells etc:

```
tmux # Start tmux session
echo some-text
some-text
...
bash # Start new bash
...
```

Hm, I want to copy `echo` output from the outer session.
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>,<kbd>[</kbd> - Enter copy mode to copy text or view the history
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, `some`, <kbd>Enter</kbd> - Search `some`
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> - Start selection
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> - Select to the end of line
<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> - Copy selection
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>,<kbd>]</kbd> - Paste the most recently copied buffer of text