# What is it "!!" and how it connected to `$_` or `$?`?

Tags: bash

I was playing with string substitution while learning a bit more of bash, and I have add `!!` into some dummy example `echo ${TEST/hey/!!}`...

I was surprised that `!!` was replaced with last entered command... what is it? is it somehow connected to magick codes link `$?` or `$_` or even `-`. Is there anything else I can use in same manner in bash?

Comment: Related (but doesn’t address the relationship with parameter expansion): [Understanding the exclamation mark (!) in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3747/86440).

Comment: They're not related, and they're not performed at the same stage (even if `$_` and `!$` will get you the same with simple commands). `!` will get you the "bang" / history expansion, a mechanism inherited from `csh`. Go read the "HISTORY EXPANSION" chapter from the bash manual.

Answer (score 1):

Bash performs different kinds of automatic replacements called expansions. For example, some of them are:

- History Expansion
- Path Expansion
- Parameter Expansion
- and others...

When you include `!!` bash automatically replaces by previous executed command. The character `!` performs history expansion. For example `!10` is replaced by the 10th command in the command history. 
`$` does parameter and variable expansion. All of those characters: `-`, `_`, and `?` are special parameter for bash.

The best source to learn about it is the bash manual: [Bash Reference Manual: Top](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html)

The example you mention `echo ${TEST/hey/!!}` include both parameter and history expansions.