# grep with regex doesn't find a match

Tags: grep, regular-expression

The number must not start with 0.

I ran this grep command with reg ex

`❯ echo "#time 1m"  | grep -E -o "#time\s(?!0)\d{1,2}[m|h|d]"`

and get the following output:

`zsh: event not found: 0`

My attempt in a graphical reg ext tester shows me a match:[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> zsh: event not found: 0
> ```

This is due to the shell treating the `!` as the trigger for history expansion. Either put the string in single quotes, or disable history expansion with `set +o histexpand` (or `setopt nohistexpand` in zsh, or `set +H` in Bash). See e.g. [Understanding the exclamation mark (!) in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3747/170373)

> ```
> ... grep -E -o "#time\s(?!0)\d{1,2}[m|h|d]"
> ```

Note that `\s`, `(?!...)`, and `\d` are part of Perl regexes, not standard extended regexes that `grep -E` uses. Also, `[m|h|d]` matches any single character that is one of `m`, `|`, `h`, or `d`. It'd be better written as `[mhd|]` or so, but you probably mean `[mhd]` (or `(m|h|d)` which is just a longer way of writing it).

You'll likely have to rewrite the regex as a standard ERE, or switch to a tool that can use Perl regexes, like `grep -P` in GNU grep.

See [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with the RE. It's the shell being allowed to see inside your string and trying to evaluate it. (That's why the error message starts with `zsh` rather than, say, `grep`.) To prevent this, use single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`)