# Execute a file in an application based on the file's extension in bash

Tags: bash

After reading [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-line-features-or-tricks/221#221) about a zsh feature:

> If a given extension has a suffix
>   alias, you can execute a file with
>   that extention directly, and ZSH will
>   launch the given program and pass the
>   filename as an argument.

Is there something similar to bash? That is, if a given file has an extension, how to directly execute that file, automatically launching a program just by calling the file's name? So doing

> program /path/to/foo.ext
>
> /path/to/foo.ext

would equivalent to the same [zsh feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-line-features-or-tricks/221#221)? Is this feature available in newer versions of bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am not familiar with every feature of Bash, I do not believe this is a built-in feature of the Bash shell.  I was unable to find this feature in the relevant sections of the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).

You may be able to cobble something together using `trap`.  From `help trap`:

> Trap signals and other events.
>
> Defines and activates handlers to be run when the shell receives signals
>   or other conditions.

Thus by using the command:

```
$ trap my_function ERR
```

I can ensure that `my_function` is called whenever a command fails.  `my_function` could be a function that parses the previous command, looking for known extensions and calling the appropriate command based on that extension.

Depending on your interest, writing such a function may be more or less interesting than moving to the z shell.

Comment: Well, I think using this approach with xdg-open pointed out by @akira because of @NES answer is the way to go. Until them, just an alias do xdg-open is good to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Linux, you could try setting up [binfmt misc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Binfmt_misc_for_Java).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell) instead of Bash. It has the functionality you're searching and lots interesting more.

For your example. Just type in

```
open manual.pdf
```

and it opens the pdf file with the associated program.

Comment: so your answer is "no." plus: your 'open' is most likely only working on mac in the way you think it works. on linux it is a symlink to `openvt` which "starts a program on a new virtual terminal". on linux it would be `xdg-open` or `gnome-open`.

Comment: @akira: Indeed, using xdg-open works in my Ubuntu machine. I think I'll just create an "open" alias to xdg-open.