# Opening py files in vim by default without having to type "vim filename.py"

Tags: shell, zsh, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh

I was wondering whether it is possible to open python files in vim, without typing "vim" in front of it. For example:
Instead of:

```
vim filename.py
```

simply

```
$ filename.py
```

Would open the file in vim.

I believe it is not upto `.vimrc` but `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` (in my case), which would interpret the `.py` files to be executable with `vim` or something. I am using ubuntu (wsl2), with zsh (oh-my-zsh).
It is possible that this has been asked before, but I couldn't find such a question. Thank you.

Comment: How would you run the "filename.py" script? If you **don't** make the file executable then you could leverage the command not found handler https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333259/194382. This seems a strange thing to want to do, to save typing 4 characters. Perhaps you would be better off defining a keyboard macro so say typing control-e just went to the start of the line and added v i m space return. That way you could type the filename and return to execute the file or the filename and control-e to edit the file?

Comment: Yes, the macro seems like a good idea. Thanks. By the way, for running the script I can type `python filename.py` which I have no problem doing. But keyboard shortcut would work for me.

Comment: While I know I've answered the question below, let me also recommend, since you are running on WSL, that you consider Visual Studio Code for Python editing.  I love Vim, but VSCode's WSL integration (with the "Remote - WSL" extension) is pretty amazing.  There's also an extension for vi keybindings, of course.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I'm still not accustomed with the feel of VSCode. But yes, I plan to gradually switch to it. The fact that you can run jupyter nb in it is pretty useful too. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my personal surprise, yes, there's a way in `zsh`.  [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5055/432493) led me to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/221/432493) talking about "suffix aliases" in `zsh`.  Not that yours is a duplicate -- The first question was about a `bash` way to do it; the other answer was just about "favorite `zsh` features".

To do it with a suffix alias:

```
alias -s py=vim
```

Add that to your `~/.zshrc` to make it permanent.

Personally, I'd recommend against it for at least two reasons.  First and foremost, as @pizzapants184 pointed out in a comment, this overrides even the ability to execute a Python file using its path.  For example, `./run_me.py` will not execute, even if it is set as executable, and even if it has a shebang line (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env python3` or `#!/usr/bin/python3`).  It's a neat feature, but it would be nice, IMHO, if it were "smarter."

Also, the extra 3 characters ("`vi` ") become such muscle memory that will serve you well on other systems that you haven't configured this way or that don't have `zsh` installed.

#### Alternative method

And while I still don't necessarily recommend it, you can set the shebang line for an individual file to force it to load in `vim` when executed:

- As the first line of the file (we'll call it `edit_me.py`):

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env vi
  ```
- Set the file executable:

  ```
  chmod +x edit_me.py
  ```
- Running it (e.g. `./edit_me.py`) will open it in `vim` (or fallback to `vi` if not available).