# Create and move to a directory in one command - unix

Tags: shell, directory, cd-command

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a one-liner that allows me to create a directory and move into it at the same time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9123/is-there-a-one-liner-that-allows-me-to-create-a-directory-and-move-into-it-at-th)

I know this is a very basic question but I can't seem to figure out what to search for to get the answer.

In linux/unix/ssh I know you can create a folder like this:

> `mkdir path/to/myfolder`

And you can move to that folder like this:

> `cd path/to/myfolder`

But is it possible to create it and move to it in one command, to prevent having to type the path twice?

Answer (score 9):

Just make a function doing it for you. In bash for example:

```
mkdircd(){ mkdir "$1" && cd "$1" ; }
```

example

```
mkdircd hello
```

Comment: I wouldn't be sure where to add this so that it's always available—if it's relevant, I'm using this in the context of 1) Terminal on a Mac, and 2) SSH server running CentOS.

Comment: Add it to `~/.bashrc` if you're using Bash.

Answer (score 8):

If you use **Bash** you can do:

```
mkdir path/to/myfolder
cd $_
```

The special variable $_ expands to the last parameter of the last command. Because of this it only works if you type it directly afterwards.

See here for more information:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters

Comment: alternatively, press up-arrow and edit the line to change `mkdir` to `cd`, or just type `^mkdir^cd<ENTER>`

Comment: `!$` does the same thing.