# Run two commands on one argument (without scripting)

Tags: command-line

How can I perform two commands on one input, without typing that input twice?

For example, the stat command tells a lot about a file, but doesn't indicate its file type:

```
stat fileName
```

The file command, tells what type a file is:

```
file fileName
```

You can perform this in one line this way:

```
stat fileName ; file fileName
```

However, you have to type the fileName twice.

How can you execute both commands on the same input (without typing the input or a variable of the input twice)?

In Linux, I know how to pipe outputs, but how do you pipe inputs?

Comment: Just to be clear, those aren't "inputs", they're arguments (aka parameters).  *Input* can be piped via `<` (input from file to the left side) or `|` (input from stream to the right side).  There's a difference.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but maybe an answer to your problem: In bash, the `yank-last-arg` command (default shortcut `Meta-.` or `Meta-_`; `Meta` often being the left `Alt` key) will copy the last parameter from the preceding command line into the current one. So, after executing `stat fileName` you type `file [Meta-.]` and do not have to type that `fileName` again. I always use that.

Comment: And the difference is that `<` and `>` are *redirection*, not *piping*. A pipeline connects two processes, while redirection simply reassigns stdin/stdout.

Comment: @bdowning: Yeah, but you're redirecting the pipe though aren't you. You can redirect the start of a pipeline to be reading from a file on disk, or you can redirect the end of a pipeline to be writing to a file on disk. Still piping. ;-)

Comment: Related (but more specialized): [Is there a one-liner that allows me to create a directory and move into it at the same time?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9123/80216)

Comment: Learn to define functions in your shell.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
$ stat filename && file "$_"
```

Example:

```
$ stat /usr/bin/yum && file "$_"
  File: ‘/usr/bin/yum’
  Size: 801         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 804h/2052d  Inode: 1189124     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:rpm_exec_t:s0
Access: 2014-06-11 22:55:53.783586098 +0700
Modify: 2014-05-22 16:49:35.000000000 +0700
Change: 2014-06-11 19:15:30.047017844 +0700
 Birth: -
/usr/bin/yum: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

That works in `bash` and `zsh`. That also works in `mksh` and `dash` but only when interactive. In AT&T ksh, that only works when the `file "$_"` is on a different line from the `stat` one.

Comment: The `!$` one won't work because `!$` expands to the last word of the last history event (so of the previously entered command line, not of the stat command).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Oh, yes, my mistake, I deleted it.

Answer (score 33):

Probably going to get my knuckles rapped for this, here's a hacky combination of bash brace expansion and eval that seems to do the trick

```
eval {stat,file}" fileName;"
```

Comment: Sorry, but [I cannot resist](http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/503/166/bfc.gif).

Comment: brace expansion originated in `csh`, not `bash`. `bash` copied it from `ksh`. That code will work in all of csh, tcsh, ksh, zsh, fish and bash.

Comment: Too bad you lose the ability to "tab out" (auto-complete) the fileName, due to the quote.

Comment: Sorry, but I [could not resist](https://media.giphy.com/media/rXiSxf0Vnd8mA/giphy.gif) either

Comment: sorry what's the problem here with `eval`? (referring to top comments)

Answer (score 30):

With `zsh`, you can use anonymous functions:

```
(){stat $1; file $1} filename
```

With `es` lambdas:

```
@{stat $1; file $1} filename
```

You could also do:

```
{ stat -; file -;} < filename
```

(doing the `stat` first as the `file` will update the access time).

I'd do:

```
f=filename; stat "$f"; file "$f"
```

though, that's what variables are for.

Comment: { stat -; file -;} < filename  (the dashes corrupt the output of the stat command slightly - having blank File output). I see they're necessary, but are they doing?

Comment: `{ stat -; file -;} < filename` is magic. `stat` must be checking to see that its stdin is connected to a file and reporting the file's attributes? Presumably not advancing the pointer on stdin therefore allowing `file` to sniff stdin contents

Comment: @1_CR, yes. `stat -` tells `stat` to do an `fstat()` on its fd 0.

Comment: The `{ $COMMAND_A -; $COMMAND_B; } < filename` variant won't work in the general case if $COMMAND_A actually reads any input; e.g. `{ cat -; cat -; } < filename` will print the contents of filename only once.

Comment: `stat -` is handled specially since coreutils-8.0 (Oct 2009), in versions prior to that you will get an error (unless you have a file called `-` from a previous experiment, in which case you'll get the wrong results...)

Comment: @mr.spuratic. Yes, and BSDs, IRIX and zsh stats won't recognise it either. With zsh and IRIX stat, you can use `stat -f0` instead.

Answer (score 11):

All of these answers seem like scripting to me, to a greater or lesser extent.  For a solution that really involves no scripting, and assumes that you're sitting at the keyboard typing into a shell, you can try:

```
stat somefile Enter
file Esc_   Enter
```

In bash, zsh, and ksh at least, in both vi and emacs modes, pressing Escape and then underscore inserts the last word from the previous line into the edit buffer for the current line.

Or, you can use history substitution:

```
stat somefile Enter
file !$ Enter
```

In bash, zsh, csh, tcsh, and most other shells, `!$` is replaced with the last word of the previous command line when the current command line is parsed.

Comment: what other options are available in zsh/bash that are like `Esc _` ? Can you please link with the official documentation?

Comment: Bash: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Line-Editing and search for "M-_"

Comment: zsh: http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshzle and search for "insert-last-word"

Comment: @shadyabhi ^ Links for both bash and zsh's standard keybindings.  Note that bash is just using readline, so (most of) the bash ones will work in any application that uses the readline library.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is similar to a couple of the others:

```
stat filename  &&  file !#:1
```

Unlike the other answers, which automatically repeat the *last* argument from the previous command, this one requires you to count:

```
ls -ld filename  &&  file !#:2
```

Unlike some of the other answers, this does not require quotes:

```
stat "useless cat"  &&  file !#:1
```

or

```
echo Sometimes a '$cigar' is just a !#:3.
```

Answer (score 3):

The way I have found to do this reasonably simply is using xargs, it takes a file  / pipe and converts its contents into a program arguments . This can be combined with tee which splits a stream and sends it to two or more programs, In your case you need:

```
echo filename | tee >(xargs stat) >(xargs file) | cat
```

Unlike many of the other answers this will work in bash and most other shells under Linux. I shall suggest this is a good use case of a variable but if you absolutely cannot use one this is the best way to do it only with pipes and simple utilities (assuming you do not have a particularly fancy shell).

Additionally you can do this for any number of programs by simply adding them in the same manner as these two after the tee.

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments there are a couple of flaws in this answer, the first is the potential for output interlacing. This can be fixed as so:

```
echo filename | tee >(xargs stat) >(( wait $!; xargs file )) | cat
```

This will force the commands to run in turn and output will never be interlaced.

The second issue is avoiding process substitution which is not available in some shells, this can be achieved by using tpipe instead of tee as so:

```
echo filename | tpipe 'xargs stat' | ( wait $!; xargs file )
```

This should be portable to nearly any shell (I hope) and solves the issues in the other commend, however I am writing this last one from memory as my current system does not have tpipe available.

Comment: Process substitution is a ksh feature that only works in `ksh` (not the public domain variants), `bash` and `zsh`. Note that `stat` and `file` will run concurrently, so possibly their output will be intertwined (I suppose you're using `| cat` to force output buffering to limit that effect?).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You are correct about cat, when using it I have not managed to ever produce a case of interlaced input when using it. However I am going to try something to produce a more portable solution momentarily.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to a couple of the other answers,
but is more portable than [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136604/23408)
and much simpler than [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136629/23408):

```
sh -c 'stat "$0"; file "$0"' filename
```

or

```
sh -c 'stat "$1"; file "$1"' sh filename
```

in which `sh` is assigned to `$0`. 
Although it is three characters more to type,
this (second) form is preferable
because that `$0` is the name you give to that inline script. 
It's used, for instance, in error messages by the shell for that script,
like when `file` or `stat` can't be found or can't be executed
for any reason.

---

If you want to do

```
stat filename1 filename2 filename3 …; file filename1 filename2 filename3 …
```

for an arbitrary number of files, do

```
sh -c 'stat "$@"; file "$@"' sh filename1 filename2 filename3 …
```

which works because `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" "$3" …`.

Comment: That `$0` is the name you want to give to that inline script. It's used for instance in error messages by the shell for that script. Like when `file` or `stat` can't be found or can't be executed for any reason. So, you want something meaningful here. If not inspired, just use `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking a wrong question, at least for what you are trying to do.
`stat` and `file` commands are taking parameters which is the name of a file and not the content of it. It is later on the command which does reading of the file identified by the name you are specifying.

A pipe is supposed to have two ends, one used as input and another one as output and this make sense as you might need to do different processing along the way with different tools until you get needed result. Saying that you know how to pipe outputs but don't know how to pipe inputs is not correct in principle.

In your case you don't need a pipe at all since you have to provide the input in a form of a file name. And even if those tools (`stat` and `file`) would read stdin, pipe is not relevant here again as input should not be altered by any of the tool when it gets to the second one.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different references to 'input' here, so I will give a few scenarios with understanding it in mind first.  **For your quick answer to the question in shortest form**:

```
stat testfile < <($1)> outputfile
```

The above will perform a stat on testfile, take (redirect) it's STDOUT and include that into the next special function (the <() part) then output the final results of whatever that was, into a new file (outputfile).  The file is called, then referenced with bash built-ins ($1 each time after, until you begin a new set of instructions).

Your question is great, and there are several answers and ways to do this, but it does indeed change with what you are doing specifically.

For instance, you can loop that as well, which is quite handy.  A common usage of this is, in psuedo-code mindset, is:

```
run program < <($output_from_program)> my_own.log
```

Taking that in and expanding on that knowledge allows you to create things such as:

```
ls -A; (while read line; do printf "\e[1;31mFound a file\e[0m: $line\n"; done) < <(/bin/grep thatword * | /usr/bin/tee -a files_that_matched_thatword)
```

This will perform a simple ls -A on your current directory, then tell while to loop through each result from the ls -A to (and here's where it's tricky!) grep "thatword" in each of those results, and only perform the previous printf (in red) if it actually found a file with "thatword" in it.  It will also log the results of the grep into a new text file, files_that_matched_thatword.

Example output:

```
ls -A; (while read line; do printf "\e[1;31mFound a file\e[0m: $line\n"; done) < <(/bin/grep thatword * | /usr/bin/tee -a files_that_matched_thatword)

index.html
```

All of that simply printed the ls -A result, nothing special.  Add something for it to grep this time:

```
echo "thatword" >> newfile
```

Now re-run it:

```
ls -A; (while read line; do printf "\e[1;31mFound a file\e[0m: $line\n"; done) < <(/bin/grep thatword * | /usr/bin/tee -a files_that_matched_thatword)

files_that_matched_thatword  index.html  newfile

Found a file: newfile:thatword
```

While perhaps a more exhausting answer than you're looking for at present, I believe keeping handy notes like this around will benefit you much more in future endeavours.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all file names in the current directory.

```
sh -c "$(printf 'stat -- "$1";file -- "$1";shift%.0b\n' *)" -- *
```

Comment: Assuming the file names don't contain double quote, backslash, dollar, backtick, `}`... characters and don't start with `-`. Some `printf` implementations (zsh, bash, ksh93) have a `%q`. With `zsh`, that could be: `printf 'stat %q; file %1$q\n' ./* | zsh`

Comment: @StephaneChezales - all of that is fixed now except for the possibility of the hardquote. I could handile that with a single `sed` `s///` I guess, but its about of scope - and if people are putting that in their filenames they should be using windows.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - nevermind - I forgot how easy those were to handle.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not an answer to the question as asked: “How can you execute both commands on the same input (***without typing the input … twice***)?” (emphasis added). Your answer applies to all files in the current directory – ***and it includes `*` twice***. You might as well say `stat -- *; file -- *`.

Comment: @Scott - the input is not typed twice - `*` is expanded. The *expansion* of `*` plus the two commands *for every argument in* `*` is the input. See? `printf commands\ %s\;shift *`

Comment: @Scott - the `*` is *expanded* into the same *argument list* for both `printf` *and* for `sh`. So, for every one of its arguments, `printf` prints its format string `'commands "$1" ; shift\n'`. So if there are thirty files in `*`, `sh` gets *as input* 30 copies of that command - which it also applies to its argument list as *expanded* from `*`. You see? Not only does it not type it twice, it doesn't do it thirty times either - only once.

Comment: @Scott - arguments - not input. What are you going on about? Can I explain the previous in some other way that you will better understand?

Comment: Perhaps we're having some fundamental disagreement of the meaning of the word ***typing***.

Comment: @Scott - I do not disagree that a `*` is *typed* twice - but in neither of the cases that it is typed is it *input*.

Comment: @Scott - No, I do not - as you've just said - I have answered the question *as asked*.

Comment: I give up. We're not on the same planet.

Comment: @Scott - no, I might not *as well* `stat -- * ; file -- *` - you see, those commands work the *entire* argument list separately - here they are interleaved - one execution each for each argument. It's much closer to `for a ; stat -- "$a" ; file -- "$a" ; done` except that this same strategy can reliably cooperate argument lists between shell processes - like across a `|pipe`, or, as demonstrated, from within a subshell.