# Looking for a way turn multiples commands with same parameter into a one liner

Tags: bash, shell

I sometimes end up doing things like:

**Example**:

from `~/blah`

```
$ mkdir ~/test-tmp
$ cp * ~/test-tmp
$ cd ~/test-tmp
```

using the destination dir 3 times in a row. Isn't there a way to turn these into a one-liner command?

Comment: You can refer something here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136599/run-two-commands-on-one-argument-without-scripting/136624#136624

Comment: @Gnouc you should make it as an answer to this question

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this?

`mkdir ~/test-tmp && cp * ~/test-tmp && cd ~/test-tmp`

or

```
function mm() {
  local dir=$1
  if [ ! -z "$dir" ]
  then
    mkdir ~/${dir} && cp * ~/${dir} && cd ~/${dir}
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In bash, the argument to the last command you ran is saved as `!$`. This is documented in `man bash`:

```
   !      Start a history substitution, except when followed by  a  blank,
          newline,  carriage return, = or ( (when the extglob shell option
          is enabled using the shopt builtin).
   [...]
   $      The last argument.
```

So, you could do

```
$ mkdir ~/test-tmp ; cp * !$ ; cd !$
```

Or, simply

```
$ mkdir ~/test-tmp
$ cp * !$
$ cd !$
```

Answer (score 2):

If your concern includes the retyping of `~/test-tmp`, you can do the following to shorten and combine the commands into a one-liner:

```
D=~/test-tmp; mkdir $D; cp * $D; cd $D
```

Please note that if your path includes spaces, you have to quote the assignment **and** where you use the variable:

```
D="~/test tmp"; mkdir "$D" ; cp * "$D"; cd "$D"
```

Comment: nice one! although the `export` isn't required in this case.

Comment: @fduff You are right. From my bash history I see I first tried `A=1 echo $A` , when that did not work (because of the missing semi-colon and echo being build-in), I both added the export and the semi-colon in the next try