# Absolute path from user input without losing symlinks inside

Tags: bash, shell, symlink

Is it possible to convert in a shell script a user input path (absolute or relative) to the absolute path but without losing the symlinks inside, e.g. /a/b/c is the current user dir and c is a symlink to /a/b/s:

```
input .      => result /a/b/c
input ./d    => result /a/b/c/d
input ../c   => result /a/b/c
input /a/b/c => result /a/b/c
(readlink converts it to /a/b/s, but I need /a/b/c)
```

Comment: “Without losing the symlinks” and eliminating `..` is contradictory: if `f` is a symlink to `/elsewhere`, for `f/../stuff`, do you want `/a/b/stuff` (eliminating `..` without looking up symlinks, but you end up with a path that doesn't lead to the same file) or `/elsewhere/stuff` (which is correct but doesn't go through a symlink) or `/a/b/f/../stuff` (which is correct but retains `..`)? The considerations in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9123/is-there-a-one-liner-that-allows-me-to-create-a-directory-and-move-into-it-at-th/9124#9124 may be of interest.

Comment: Hi @Gilles: thanks and you are right with your example, but in my case this doesn't play a major role.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you need to use `realpath` with `-s`:

> -s, --strip
>       Only strip .  and .., components, but do not resolve symbolic links.

```
$ realpath -s a/b/c
/tmp/a/b/c
$ readlink a/b/c
s
```

Comment: Thank you, but realpath is not installed by default and the script should run on servers where I can't install it.

Comment: What system is that? You don't need to be root to install a program, you can put in your home dir and add it to your `$PATH`.

Comment: I just installed realpath to test it. `realpath -s /a/b/c` and `realpath -s ../c/d` work as expected, but not with one dot at the beginning: `realpath -s ./d` outputs `/a/b/s/d`. But this can be fixed in the script. I will test to copy the binary file to the destination server. Hope it will work :-) Thanks again.