# how to add a custom option to the mkdir command

Tags: bash, function, cd-command, mkdir

I have created lots of directories and I would to make my life lazy and to auto `cd` into the directory that I made with the option of `-g` with the result of `mkdir -g foo`

The terminal would be like this:

```
User:/$ mkdir -g foo
User:/foo/$
```

I have looked at this page but with no success.

[Is there a one-liner that allows me to create a directory and move into it at the same time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9123/is-there-a-one-liner-that-allows-me-to-create-a-directory-and-move-into-it-at-th)

I have tried in my `.bash_profile` with this command, but it just overrides the command entirely. (and realizing that it is an infinite loop later)

```
mkdir() {
 if "$1" -eq "-g"
  mkdir "$2"
  cd "$2"
 else
  ## do the regular code
 fi
}
```

The other thing is that I don't want to make more aliases because I will eventually forget all of the aliases that I have.

So not I don't want this:

the command entirely. (and realizing that it is an infinite loop later)

```
mkcd() {
 if "$1" -eq "-g"
  mkdir "$2"
  cd "$2"
 else
  ## do the regular code
 fi
}
```

I know that I most likely don't have the option thingy right, please correct me on that, but any help would be awesome!

Comment: The simplest fix is to use `$(which mkdir)` to invoke the system `mkdir`. I strongly recommend making an alias with a different name though.

Comment: Making an alias with a different syntax and behaviour to an existing UNIX command may be an eternal source of confusion and errors if you try to `source` other people's code. I would really advise to make a different alias for your command, e.g. `mkcdir`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `command` builtin to call an external command, bypassing any function of the same name. Also:

- What follows `if` is an ordinary command. To perform a string comparison, invoke the `test` built-in, or the `[` builtin with the same syntax plus a final `]`, or the `[[ … ]]` construct which has a more relaxed syntax. See [using single or double bracket - bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/using-single-or-double-bracket-bash) for more information.
- The `-eq` operator is for comparing integers. Use `=` to compare strings.
- I added some limited support for passing multiple arguments (including options such as `-p`). Below I call `cd` only if `mkdir` succeeded, and I call it on the last argument passed to the function.
- `-g` will only be recognized as the very first argument. Parsing options to locate and remove it from whatever position it's in is possible, but harder.

```
mkdir () {
  local do_cd=
  if [ "$1" = "-g"]; then
    do_cd=1
    shift
  fi
  command mkdir "$@" &&
  if [ -n "$do_cd" ]; then
    eval "cd \"\${$#}\""
  fi
}
```

I don't recommend defining your custom options. They won't be shown in `--help` or man pages. They aren't more memorable than defining a command with a different name: either you don't remember that you have them, and there's no advantage compared to a command with a different name, or you don't remember that they're custom, and then you can find this out immediately with a custom name by asking the shell whether it's a built-in command or function (`type mkcd`), which is not the case with a custom option. There are use cases for overriding a standard command, but this is not one.

Comment: also typing `mkdir -g` won't autocomplete, but `mkcddir` or whatever might.