# Zsh: How to create a directory and file inside it with one command?

Tags: files, zsh, directory, touch

I am curious whether it is possible to create a directory and file inside this directory with one command, similar to `mkdir -p` but for a text file and intermediate directory.

I read through the `touch` manual and found nothing.
Neither I could find the answer on unix stackexchange.

Is there any way to do so (perhaps without using other command rather than touch), since it is pretty routine task to initiate a new directory with a file?

Comment: Why do you need these two actions to be a single command? 

Also, you can write such an utility or a bash script which does this as well. Something akin to `mkdir -p "$1" && touch "$1/$2"`

Comment: Please define *command* here? If by that, you mean executing an utility, you should be able to do it with zero command as `mkdir` can be made builtin in `zsh`. `(mkdir -p foo && touch foo/bar)` is a *compound command* and a *command* in the POSIX shell grammar definition of those for that matters.

Comment: Why? Is there a use-case? What do you want the contents of that file to be? Its permissions?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9123/117549

Comment: Thank you all. I am a very beginner, and maybe it is not the optimal way to do it, but usually I create a project folder and initiate it with index.html or something like that, that is, the starting point of my project. I thought it was common, but it might be a my mistake.
What I was trying to find is if there was an alternative method to create a file specifying the path and creating the intermediate folders with one command, like with mkdir -p, but probably the solution is doing it with function, as && is no shorter. Don't know whether I'll use a function, but thank you anyway!

Comment: Dear Jeff, thank you for your response. Yes, this answers my question, however I wanted to know if there are any other ways to solve the same problem, i.e. if there's a one-liner like above mentioned mkdir -p, but for files. Therefore, I created this post anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the `install` command from GNU `coreutils` with the `-D` option which can copy a file and create the directories leading to them in one go (and also let you specify the ownership and permissions). By default, it creates executable files and doesn't honour the umask as it's typically used as a dev tool in `make install` stages.

```
install -m u=rw,go=r -D /dev/null some/new/file
```

(the permissions of the directory components it creates are always `u=rwx,go=rx`).

Or you could always implement it as a `create` Zsh function such as:

```
create() {
  local file ret=0
  for file do
    mkdir -p -- "$file:h" && true >> "$file" || ret=$?
  done
  return "$ret"
}
```

Though creating an *empty* regular file seems a bit pointless to me.

Generally, you'd do:

```
mkdir -p some/dir
your-editor some/dir/some-file
```

To create some-file (the file would be created as soon you save it (with actual content) in your editor).

Or any other command that creates some content like:

```
some-command > some/dir/some-file
wget -o some/dir/some-file https://example.com/whatever
cp source some/dir/some-file
...etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have,

```
#!/bin/zsh -

### Create a text file ###

[[ -z $1 ]] && exit 1

file="$1"

mkdir --parents ${file:h}

$EDITOR $file
```

The command is called `ct` (create text), so I run it like: `ct path/to/dir/file.txt`.

Unlike other answers in other threads, this doesn't make an unnecessary call to `dirname`, nor does it use the (arguably) denser syntax of `${file#...}` or `${file%...}`. It also doesn't need to be a function, since it's not changing the shell.