# If ^a^b replaces "a" once in the last command, what do I use to replace all occurrences of "a"?

Tags: bash, zsh, command-history

In bash, if I run this command:

```
echo aaaaaaa
```

I get `aaaaaaa` (duh)

But then if I type in

```
^a^b
```

I end up with `baaaaaa`

What would I type to end up with `bbbbbbb` ?

Comment: While it doesn't save keystrokes except in very rare complex cases, you also have the option of `fc` to edit commands in your preferred editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In bash, I don't think you can combine the `^` shortcut with any modifier. That leaves the long form:

```
!!:gs/a/b/
```

In zsh, the `G` modifier is a special case, you can use it with `^`:

```
^a^b^:G
```

Answer (score 4):

`^search^replacement` is syntactic sugar for `!:s/search/replacement/`, which is explained in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67/73). The version that replaces all instances is `!:gs/search/replacement/`; I think that's the shortest form there is