# Terminal with "repeat last" button

Tags: terminal, command-history, gui

I'm often compiling stuff and therefore repeating the same command over and over, so I'd like to benefit from my "visual memory" and have a sort of "repeat last command" button attached to a terminal. More precisely, here is how I see it:

- My "special" terminal would be just like a standard terminal emulator, with an extra input line at the bottom, which would have a "run" button attached to it. Clicking the button would run the command *without* erasing it.
- Maybe even an arbitrary number of such commands could be stacked (since I often need to alternate between 2 or 3 commands).

I know I can use just <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> with the keyboard to redo the last command, but what often happens is that I forget I just had to type another command (to fix something, or whatever) so <kbd>↑</kbd> will not bring the right command from the history. So instead of a reflex, I have to actually read (at least skim) the command before pressing Enter.

Is there such a contraption somewhere? I often use several terminals precisely to make sure each always has the "right" command as last, but my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> skills usually make me tab to the wrong window. And I need terminal information, such as the environment and cwd, so I cannot just try and "integrate" it in my code editor. I mean, using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> would not work (since I also need the read the output from the terminal). I just want to be able to use the best of both keyboard and visual memory (via clicks) at the same time.

Comment: How about an alias with your compile command - a very short alias, like two or three letters?

Comment: How would your button know which command you need if "up-Enter" isn't always what you want? Most shells have sophisticated tools for recalling and executing commands in the history, in bash `!m` would recall the last command entered starting with `m` (e.g. `make`).

Comment: Have a look at [difference between termian and a shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con). The problem is that the terminal typically knows nothing about your shell, e.g. it doesn't know in which directory (or host) you currently are and can't execute the command. You should try to enhance your setup and build from within your ide/editor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your ideas! I'll read them in detail.
Anyway, I think a "fake screenshot" could help explain what I was thinking about. (Images are taken from the internet BTW).
This is how I'd see my "extended terminal":

![My Terminal](http://i.imgur.com/2Zg9c.jpg)

Just a plain terminal attached to a "command bar" at the bottom. The idea is: in the event of a click on the "Run" button, the current command line in the shell is removed and the text in the "command bar" becomes the current command, which is sent to the terminal. Very simple, no autocompletion or anything necessary.

Comment: (sorry, I cannot post longer messages). Also, when the button is clicked, the text remains in place, so I don't have to type it again. The idea would be to later make some kind of "hover" bar (like on this fake screenshot: ![IDE example](http://i.imgur.com/pWL27.png) that stays on top of the IDE. Its position is more or less fixed, so I can use my visual memory to execute the command. Even if there are several of them, I find it easier to manage than the history (though those advanced commands may help).

Comment: To sum up, I was thinking about some sort of "Eclipse Ant build button", but independent of any IDE. I once coded a simple version in Java, so I thought there should already be something like that somewhere, my question was mainly to help me find it.
I hope it's clearer now... by the way, a command bar without the attached shell is less useful, since I have no way to read the output (e.g. in case of an error).
So all it is, in fact, is an alternative way to input text into a shell using the mouse. Nothing more, nothing less...

Comment: This is perhaps similar to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147563/how-do-i-repeat-the-last-command-without-using-the-arrow-keys

Answer (score 2):

I think that history expansion might be very helpful here. For example, typing `!p` will execute the last command starting with 'p'. Similarly `!vi` will execute the last command starting with 'vi', and so on. More info [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators). If you are not sure which of those was the last one, you can set shell option `histverify` (`shopt -s histverify`), so you can still edit (or inspect) the command before you execute it. More on this [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html).

Alternatively, you can use the history search functionality. In bash, hit `Ctrl+R` and type the command you want to find in the history (starting with the most recent one that matches the criteria). Hitting `Ctrl+R` repeateadly then will bring back older commands that match your criteria. More info [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Searching) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Searching.html)

If you are keen, you can modify your readline's inputrc, such that the up/down arrows do the history search for you. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.org/wiki/Inputrc_for_bash_history_completion_using_up/down_arrows) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File.html#Readline-Init-File).

Comment: In addition to this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67/14084

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the history functionality of your shell. In my zsh:

```
!!
```

repeats the last command.

Type `history` to take a look at the last few entries.

To get your desired buffer in the shell:

```
man zshzle
```

or

```
man readline
```

Also, you can tab expand the completions

```
make long_target
ls some_path
...
make l<TAB> # prints 'make long_target' without running it
```

use wildcards, expansions... not one bit of your use case lies outside of this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Using `zsh` you can do just that with <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Type a command then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The command will be executed and the same command will be on the line buffer after the command completes.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you need a very simple answer. Since you mentioned <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, I assume you are using (X)windows. You highlight the command with the mouse before you press "Enter". It is automatically copied to the clip board when you highlight it. To paste it, press the middle mouse button (scroll wheel) or type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Comment: I got the impression that he has the habit of hitting that command often, and, if so, using the mouse isn't a good idea.