# Social website about shell commands

Tags: shell, shell-script

I remember seeing an entire social website devoted to the question [What are your favorite command line features or tricks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-line-features-or-tricks), where you can post shell commands, tag them, comment on them, and rate and/or favorite them.  Unfortunately, I've forgotten what this site was called and can't seem to muster up enough google-fu to find it.

Anyone know of such a site (for which you can actually find a URL)?

Comment: See http://commandlinefu.com/

Comment: @manatwork: Yay! That's the one I was looking for!

Comment: Check out http://www.bashoneliners.com/ too!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse) or [shell-fu](http://www.shell-fu.org/lister.php)? ;-)