# Quicker Way to Reference a Directory?

Tags: mount, directory, symlink

This one is probably easy for all of you, but I have never had to deal with such a nested local set of directories.

If I have a path like: `/mnt/media2/Archived\ Files/_Transfer/` is there a way to "mount" that directory to `~/Transfer/` or `/mnt/transfer`?

I was looking into `symlinks`, but it talks about "how it's not always a good idea on directories because of recursive commands, etc..."

Thanks.

Comment: This is what symlinks are for.  Just try not to set up circular links, because that won't be useful to anyone, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symlinks do sound a good idea to me in this case:

```
ln -s /mnt/media2/Archived\ Files/_Transfer/ ~/Transfer
```

See also zsh's:

```
PS1='%~%# '
transfer=/mnt/media2/Archived\ Files/_Transfer/
cd ~transfer
```

Comment: For the section about zsh's above -- can I copy using that format too?  I.e. `cp ~/test.sh ~transfer/.`?  And do I still retain `rw` privileges in the linked directory?

Comment: @chow They're called [named directories](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222/73). They work in all cases where the shell interprets the string, which includes passing arguments to commands

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to (or can't) use symlinks (e.g., filesystem doesn't support, like vfat), you can also use a bind mount:

```
mount --bind "/mnt/media2/Archived Files/_Transfer" /mnt/Transfer
```

Beware that bind mounts are stronger than symlinks. E.g., `rm -Rf` will just remove a symlink when it encounters one; it'll traverse through a bind mount.

Bind mounts can only be done by root. Symlinks can be done by any user.

Comment: I do not recommend bind mounts for this. The directory tree will effectively appear twice for many purposes (backups, indexing, etc. — anything that traverses the directory tree). Symlinks are the right answer here.