# Why does `!45` get replaced with `top`?

Tags: bash, command-history, search

I was trying to a string search within Ubuntu 12.04 which went as follows:

`find . -exec grep -l "!45" {} \;`

Instead of searching for the string "!45", it was replaced with `top`.  It didn't invoke the commmand, but merely start searching for the term "top".  Until I figured out `-F` for `grep`, I thought special characters would be treated as text in between quotations.

Anywho, now that I've discovered this, **I have no idea what this is, what it's used for, or why it even exists!**

Comment: If you truly don't want ! style history control, turn it off in your ~/.bashrc: `set +H`  or `set +o histexpand`

Comment: There's a bunch of info on history commands in [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67/73)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the bash shell, `!45` returns that command from the command history (or `!32` or `!873`).

> An event designator is a reference to a command line entry in the
>   history list. Unless the reference is absolute, events are relative to
>   the current position in the history list.
>
> !
>
> Start a history substitution, except when followed by a space, tab, the end of the line, ‘=’ or ‘(’ (when the extglob shell option is
>   enabled using the shopt builtin).
>
> !n
>
> Refer to command line n.

[Check here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) for full details from the bash manual.

Comment: Ya know... I never thought about `man`ing `bash`.  +1 for the idea and hopefully not getting caught up in shell related scenarios like this one in the futur.

Comment: Been using bash for years, and never knew about that expansion - so we both learned something useful today!  Which is why I love answering questions on StackExchange.

Comment: @hydroparadise: In your defense, the bash man page is *enormous*.

Comment: @aesin and searching for '!' isn't that easy :)