# Use same arguments with different command

Tags: bash, command-history

Here's something I find myself doing often:

```
less super/long/file/name
```

Followed by:

```
vim super/long/file/name
```

Is there an easy way to pass the args of the previous command over to the next? SO I'd like to do something like

```
vim !!!
```

And have it automatically open `super/long/file/name` in `vim`.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/621012/pass-previous-commands-arguments-to-current-command

Comment: Looks like the answer is !$ but I usually hit up-arrow,home and delete the previous command and type the new one.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using `!$` should work to access the last argument of the previous command in the bash shell:

```
less super/long/file/name
vim !$
```

Also <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> can be used to paste the last argument if the readline library is enabled in emacs mode (default option).

Comment: Bash defaults to readline in emacs mode which is why the `Meta-.` trick works. This will not work if you are another mode (such as vi ... `set -o vi`), you can get readline into emacs mode with `set -o emacs`.

Comment: @Drav Sloan thanks for the comment, I have edited the answer

Answer (score 35):

If you just want the last argument from the previous command then use `!$`. If you want all the arguments from the last command then use `!*`.

#### Example

COMMAND #1:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

run #1 then this:

```
$ echo !$
echo 4
4
```

run #1 then this:

```
$ echo !*
echo 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Also I highly recommend that you check out this Unix & Linux Q&A & @Gilles' SuperUser Q&A:

- [What are your favorite command line features or tricks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-line-features-or-tricks)
- [How can I get a specific argument from a previous command in bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/210846/how-can-i-get-a-specific-argument-from-a-previous-command-in-bash)

#### Colon syntax

You can think of the `history` output as a grid. Each command is a row, each argument of each command is a column.  Like this: (`!`line`:`column).

So you can reference previous pieces of commands like this:

```
$ history | grep "105[8-9]"
 1058  echo 1 2 3 4
 1059  echo 5 6 7 8

$ echo !1058:2
echo 2
2
$ echo !1059:3
echo 7
7
```

Comment: You can also get the nth argument using `!:n`, so with your example `echo !:3` will echo `3`.

Comment: @DravSloan - yes check out the 2 links I posted. Those Q&A's cover it ALL!

Answer (score 9):

Miguel de Val-Borro gave the correct, general answer for your question, but since you said you often do this particular sequence of `less` and `vim`, it's worth mentioning that you can press <kbd>v</kbd> inside less to open your configured editor. From the less manual, under `v`:

```
Invokes an editor to edit the current file being viewed. The
editor is taken from the environment variable VISUAL if defined,
or EDITOR if VISUAL is not defined, or defaults to "vi" if  nei‐
ther VISUAL nor EDITOR is defined.
```

Comment: Nice!  Note that exiting vim in this situation returns you to running less on the file (rather than returning to the command line).

Answer (score 5):

Use  <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

It will grab the last argument from the previous command

---

You can also do a search and replace

```
less /foo/bar.txt
^less^vim
```

Comment: Do you mean `Esc`+`.` ?

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro   Whoops, yes. Dyslexified that.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
r=super/long/file/name
less $r
vi $r
ls -l $r
chmod 600 $r
cat $r >> some/other/even/longer/file/name
...
```

To save typing, you should be able to enter `super/long/file/name`, etc., using tab completion.   There is, of course, nothing special about the variable `r`; I chose it simply for proximity to the dollar sign key.