# What does !#:3 mean in a shell command

Tags: bash, command-history

The install guide for ack suggests installing the ack script using this command:

```
curl http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.14-single-file > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755 !#:3
```

I assume that the `!#:3` at the end is some kind of back-reference, but what does it mean?  Is there an equivalent in zsh?  Google has not been helpful.

Comment: It means my cat walked across the keyboard at a really bad time.

Comment: @IQAndreas: Well, it's a valid command, so your cat must be clever enough to defeat the [cat typing detector](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/how-can-i-keep-my-cat-off-my-keyboard).  Clearly this is not a useless cat.  :-)  ⁠

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a special syntax, expanded by bash. It also works for zsh.

According to the bash man page (section HISTORY EXPANSION), the pattern
expands as following:

- The *event designator* `!#` refers to the entire command line typed so far which is `curl http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.14-single-file > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755`
- `:` splits between the *event designator* (this case the entire line)
  and the *word designator* (selects a sub-part)
- the *word designator* `3` which selects the *third* word/argument (counting of words starts at zero), in this case `~/bin/ack`.

The final command line (usually displayed before executed) is:
`curl http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.14-single-file > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755 ~/bin/ack`.

For details, see the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) or very similar the [zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#History-Expansion)

Comment: I can't help but wonder: who thought this feature would ever be a good idea?

Comment: @Rhymoid, I don't use `!#` much, but `!!`, `!$`, `!*`, `!sud:p` and many others are all extremely useful and I use them all the time.  Check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67/135943

Answer (score 11):

In `bash`, it is history substitution (all history substitutions start with `!`).  Specifically, `!#` means everything on the command line so far, and the addition ':3' means the third word (starting count at 0).

So, the above command translates `!#:3` into `~/bin/ack`.