# What does the history command !# do?

Tags: bash, command-history, man

From the manual pages on `history`:

> Event Designators
>          An event designator is a reference to a command line entry in the  his‐
>          tory  list.   Unless  the reference is absolute, events are relative to
>          the current position in the history list.

```
   !      Start a history substitution, except when followed by  a  blank,
          newline, = or (.
   !n     Refer to command line n.
   !-n    Refer to the current command minus n.
   !!     Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for `!-1'.
   !string
          Refer  to the most recent command preceding the current position
          in the history list starting with string.
   !?string[?]
          Refer to the most recent command preceding the current  position
          in  the  history  list containing string.  The trailing ? may be
          omitted if string is followed immediately by a newline.
   ^string1^string2^
          Quick substitution.  Repeat the last command, replacing  string1
          with string2.  Equivalent to ``!!:s/string1/string2/'' (see Mod‐
          ifiers below).
   !#     The entire command line typed so far.
```

All the others make sense, but I can't figure out any usage for `!#` from the context.  What does it do and how is it usually used?

Comment: If this was already asked, please point me toward the question it is duplicating.  It is very hard to search for character sequences like `!#`.

Comment: Did you try it? It just repeats everything you have typed on the current command line. e.g `echo !#` executes ` echo echo`

Comment: For example, if you start a command with 'ls' then follow with ' !#', the command would read 'ls ls'. Something more useful would be modifying a copy of the current line's last argument, a long filename maybe. 'cp longname !#:$' would expand to 'cp longname longname'. Use your bind key sequence (esc-ctrl-e by default I think?) for history expansion to "expand" the !#.

Comment: In the related posts is an excellent example: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236382/what-does-3-mean-in-a-shell-command?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer here: [What does !#:3 mean in a shell command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236382/what-does-3-mean-in-a-shell-command?rq=1)

Basically, you can use it to shorten a command in combination with ':n', so:

```
$ cd /home/me/some/super/deep/dir/that/i/do/not/want/to/type/again ; ll !#:2
```

Of course this is a bit silly example, because you could just do `ll`, but you get the idea, it can be used in sh scripts.